# tikzpicture in node of another tikzpicture: how to screen of from inheriting style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I wish to create tikzpicture environments inside a node of another tikzpicture.
The problem I encouter is that styles are inherited by the inner tikzpicture.
How can I screen of the inner tikzpicture form the outer one? Or is this impossible?

The following minimal example illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

% wanted: square centered on line
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,1);
  \node[fill] at (0,.5) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

% got: square to the right of line
\begin{tikzpicture}[red]
  \node[fill] (O) {};
  \node[right=of O] {% <- this 'right of' is inherited; how to avoid?
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,1);
    \node[fill] at (0,.5) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `right of`  is not inherited but it's `right= of` Make a try with `right of= O`

Comment: A while after asking this question, I put the tikzpictures that I want to put in nodes in TeX boxes; cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66028/87. An approach which I feel is more convenient.

Comment: Yes it's a fine possibility. I use it in some cases but you can imagine the possibility to pass some arguments between the two tikzpictures. I think it's not possible with a TeX box but I'm not sure. In a general case, the TeX box is a good approach.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In this specific case you can use `anchor=center` to restore the default positioning. The `right` etc. settings modify the used anchor.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

% wanted: square centered on line
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,1);
  \node[fill] at (0,.5) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

% got: square to the right of line
\begin{tikzpicture}[red]
  \node[fill] (O) {};
  \node[right=of O] {% <- this 'right of' is inherited; how to avoid?
  \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=center]
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,1);
    \node[fill] at (0,.5) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In the general case if you want to avoid *any* settings to affect the sub-`tikzpicture` I would store it into a savebox before the main `tikzpicture` and insert that box:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

% wanted: square centered on line
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,1);
  \node[fill] at (0,.5) {};
\end{tikzpicture}


\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,1);
    \node[fill] at (0,.5) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}

% got: square to the right of line
\begin{tikzpicture}[red]
  \node[fill] (O) {};
  \node[right=of O] {% <- this 'right of' is inherited; how to avoid?
        \usebox\mybox
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So there's no command to reset all TikZ attributes to default in this case?

Comment: @user946850: No, I don't think so. Such a command would be very difficult to maintain, because *all* TikZ attributes would need need to be set with it explicitly. You can't reset things in TeX only overwrite them (with the exception of grouping of course).