# Patching tikzscale

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, patching, tikzscale, xpatch

I'm trying to patch the package `tikzscale`. Specifically, I want to remove the following lines from the package, as it does not constitute a useful error in my usecase[1].

```
\tikzscale@ifSizeDifference{\measuredFirst - \measuredSecond}{%
}{%
\PackageError{tikzscale}{Requested to scale unscalable graphic}{Do not set width or height for graphic in\MessageBreak #3}%
}%
```

I am additionally attempting to do this without editing the package itself, as I expect to share this document with other people (and on Overleaf) in such a situation that I cannot request others to edit their installs on the package, so I'm trying to do this with `regexpatch`, or `xpatch`.

`xpatch` fails with:

```
File: etoolbox.def 2018/02/11 v2.5e etoolbox debug messages (JAW)
)
[debug] tracing \patchcmd on input line 19
[debug] analyzing '\tikzscale@scaleTikzpictureTo'
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] -- macro cannot be retokenized cleanly
[debug] -> the macro may have been defined under a category
[debug]    code regime different from the current one
[debug] -> the replacement text may contain special control
[debug]    sequence tokens formed with \csname...\endcsname;
[debug] -> the replacement text may contain carriage return,
[debug]    newline, or similar characters
```

`regexpatch` fails with:

```
File: etoolbox.def 2018/02/11 v2.5e etoolbox debug messages (JAW)
)
*************************************************
* xpatch message
* `\tikzscale@scaleTikzpictureTo' is not especially defined
*************************************************
*************************************************
* xpatch message
* Macro`\tikzscale@scaleTikzpictureTo' is NOT patchable
* (Check if it contains `@' commands)
*************************************************
```

Is there a way in which this can work? Here is an MWE (while this will compile with no issues, inspecting the log will reveal the failure to patch).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\tracingpatches
\tracingxpatches
\makeatletter
\regexpatchcmd{\tikzscale@scaleTikzpictureTo} % Command to patch
{\PackageError{tikzscale}{Requested to scale unscalable graphic}.*} % Content to be replaced
{\relax} % Replacement content
{\message{Succesfully patched tikzscale!}} % Success message
{\message{Failed to patch tikzscale!}} % Failure message
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[1] My usecase is this, if it matters: I am writing `.tikz` files which themselves have `\includegraphics`, annotated in tikz. When I attempt to include them in my main document, they throw me the error `Requested to scale unscalable graphic`, however, the document compiles correctly, however, it fails on Overleaf.

An example of the `.tikz` I'm trying to include:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0){
        \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{figure2.pdf}
    };
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        % (a) (b) (c) (d) labels
        \node at (0.02,0.97){\textbf{(a)}};
        \node at (0.40,0.97){\textbf{(b)}};
        \node at (0.67,0.97){\textbf{(c)}};
        \node at (0.21,0.66){\textbf{(d)}};
        \node at (0.02,0.39){\textbf{(e)}};

        % Inset label
        \fill [white] (0.23,0.53) rectangle (0.30,0.62);
        \fill [white] (0.65,0.53) rectangle (0.75,0.62);
        \node at (0.67,0.41) {Diffraction losses};
        \node[anchor=south west] at (0.23,0.53) {$\bm{|\psi\rangle}$};
        \node[anchor=south west] at (0.65,0.53) {$\bm{T|\psi\rangle}$};

        % Optical component labels
        \node at (0.14,0.35){\small Laser};
        % \node at (0.07,0.32){\small Fiber};
        \node at (0.14,0.01){\small Pol$_1$};
        \node at (0.23,0.01){\small HWP};
        \node at (0.31,0.01){\small BS};
        \node at (0.30,0.32){\small Det$_B$};
        % \node at (0.40,0.01){\small Lens};
        % \node at (0.46,0.35){\small Metasurface};
        % \node at (0.53,0.01){\small Lens};
        \node at (0.46,-0.02){\small Metasurface};
        \node at (0.70,0.01){\small Fourier lens};
        \node at (0.74,0.20){\small QWP};
        \node at (0.83,0.20){\small Pol$_2$};
        \node at (0.95,0.03){\small Det$_A$};

        %\draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.62,0.65) rectangle (0.78,0.75);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'd recommend to also present a real world example that shows how you want to use the patch, perhaps there is a simpler possibility.

Comment: First of all, `\regexpatchcmd` requires a very different syntax; but that's not the problem: the macro `\tikzscale@scaleTikzpictureTo` does *not* contain the tokens you'd like to replace, because it's defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` (and so patching it is not covered by `regexpatch`).

Comment: I would try to avoid to nest tikzpictures. It can work, but they can be also side effects. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66037/2388. Beside this: before getting rid of an error, you should try to understand why the author added the test and the error message.

Comment: It cannot 'compile correctly' if you get an error. Really, nesting `tikzpicture`s ought not be done and can always (?) be avoided.

Comment: It compiles correctly insofar as the document is actually rendered as expected, *despite* the error coming up! I have no idea why, either. Also, I'm not trying to nest tikz pictures - my main document uses `\includegraphics` to include a `.tikz` file, which has an `\includegraphics` of a `.pdf` file. I've edited my post with an example.

Comment: The developers have previously asked for people not to post answers showing how to patch macros created with `xparse`. Doing this violates the LaTeX 3 philosophy. That is, it can be done but the developers don't want it done. In any case, there is a surely a better way of addressing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The command `\tikzscale@scaleTikzpictureTo` is defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` and neither `xpatch` nor `regexpatch` support patching such commands directly.

If you do `\xshowcmd\tikzscale@scaleTikzpictureTo` before trying the patch, you'll see

```
> \tikzscale@scaleTikzpictureTo=\protected
macro:->\__xparse_start_expandable:nNNNNn {mmm}\tikzscale@scaleTikzpictureTo 
\tikzscale@scaleTikzpictureTo  \tikzscale@scaleTikzpictureTo code
?{\__xparse_expandable_grab_m:w \__xparse_expandable_grab_m:w
\__xparse_expandable_grab_m:w }.
```

on the console and this clearly explains why the patch doesn't work: the text you'd like to replace isn't there to begin with.

A little knowledge of `xparse` will tell you what is the real macro to patch. Hint: it has a space in its name; a standard `\expandafter` trick can be used for passing it as argument to `\xpatchcmd`.

Beware also that `\regexpatchcmd` requires `l3regex` syntax (part XXVI in `interface3.pdf`); you used a syntax proper to `\xpatchcmd`.