# Reduce gap between anchor points of a tikz picture when using a macro

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a complex node multiple times in a figure and connect lines to them using code like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,decorations.markings}


\newcommand\TalentBox{
    \noindent
    \tikz {
        %figure is much more complex than this
        \node[rectangle, fill=black, font=\color{white}, minimum width=10mm, minimum height=10mm] {A}
    }
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        % multiple calls to the figure with different parameters
        \draw   (  0,  0) node(a){\TalentBox};
        \draw   (  0,  -5) node(b){\TalentBox};
        \draw   (  0,  -10) node(c){\TalentBox};

        % lines between figures have a gap on both ends
        \draw [gray,-,>=stealth, line width=6pt] (a) to (b);

        % As shown here:
        \node [circle,fill=red,   inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.south west) {};
        \node [circle,fill=blue,  inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.center) {};
        \node [circle,fill=purple,inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.north east) {};
        \node [circle,fill=green, inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.north) {};
        \node [circle,fill=orange,inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.north west) {};
        \node [circle,fill=yellow,inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.south) {};
        \node [circle,fill=brown, inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.south east) {};
        \node [circle,fill=black, inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.east) {};
        \node [circle,fill=pink,  inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.west) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: result]

The problem is that the anchor points are not at the figure but display a gap. Is there a way to avoid that gap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `inner sep` to zero: `\draw   (  0,  0) node[inner sep=0](a){\TalentBox};`

Note that nesting `tikzpicture`s can in some cases lead to problems. These problems can often be avoided by placing the inner `tikzpicture` in a box (see Joseph Wright's answer to [Proper nesting of tikzpicture environments: Reset all PGF values to their defaults](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul)), otherwise one needs to use some other technique, such as a `pic`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,decorations.markings}


\newcommand\TalentBox{%
    \tikz {
        %figure is much more complex than this
        \node[rectangle, fill=black, font=\color{white}, minimum width=10mm, minimum height=10mm] {A};
    }
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        % multiple calls to the figure with different parameters
        \draw   (  0,  0) node[inner sep=0] (a) {\TalentBox};
        \draw   (  0,  -5) node[inner sep=0] (b) {\TalentBox};
        \draw   (  0,  -10) node[inner sep=0] (c) {\TalentBox};

        % lines between figures have a gap on both ends
        \draw [gray,-,>=stealth, line width=6pt] (a) to (b);

        % As shown here:
        \node [circle,fill=red,   inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.south west) {};
        \node [circle,fill=blue,  inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.center) {};
        \node [circle,fill=purple,inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.north east) {};
        \node [circle,fill=green, inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.north) {};
        \node [circle,fill=orange,inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.north west) {};
        \node [circle,fill=yellow,inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.south) {};
        \node [circle,fill=brown, inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.south east) {};
        \node [circle,fill=black, inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.east) {};
        \node [circle,fill=pink,  inner sep=0,minimum size=4pt] at (c.west) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Above and beyond, thank you, and thanks for the warning about nesting, I will look into that link!

Answer (score 3):

why you use `newcommand`? to my opinion is better to define node style:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,decorations.markings}

\tikzset{TalentBox/.style = {rectangle, fill=black, font=\color{white},
                             minimum size=10mm, outer sep=0pt,
                             node contents= {A}
                             }
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
% multiple calls to the figure with different parameters
\draw   (  0,  0) node (a) [TalentBox];
\draw   (  0, -5) node (b) [TalentBox];
% lines between figures have a gap on both ends
\draw [gray,-,>=stealth, line width=6pt] (a) to (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

if your node should contain complex image, it can be drawn on two ways:

- as mentioned in comment below with use

  ```
   append after command={\pgfextra{ ... code ... }
  ```
- or by

  ```
   path picture={ ... code ...}
  ```

  where `code` is code of your node contents. it can be quite complex (the same as as you intent to define with definition in `\newcommand`)
- another way is define small picture `pic` and than used it like this:

  ```
  \pic (0,0) (a) {TalentBox}
  ```

  where `TalentBox` is name od `pic` definition. it can contain options which you can cal for example as `{TalentBox={a}{b}{c}}` (in case of three options) or on other ways according how you defined `pic`.
- if above mentioned approach has benefits in comparison to nested `tizpicture`? it depends on many deciding factors ... (since your content of `TalentBox` is not known, i can't estimated this)

Comment: Probably because, quote, "figure is much more complex than this".

Comment: @TorbjørnT., it may be a case, however, even complex image can be incorporated to this node style. for example with use `append after command={\pgfextra{  ... code ... }` :-)

Comment: Is it possible to use parameters and if/else in a style? if so, is it possible you could add a small example?

Comment: yes, it is possible. i suggest you to ask new question (with example, what you like to obtain) about this.