# Flipping Image Vertically

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a template with a border round the edges but struggling to flip an image to fit in.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,blindtext}
\input{inkscape.tex}
\title{Table 1}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[below left] at ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north east) {\ornament{scale=1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[below left] at ([xshift=5cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north west) {\ornament{scale=1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Using the above code with this file https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9035028

Answer (score 4):

You are nesting tikzpicture, which one [should not do](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/121799). To avoid it, you can use a savebox. As for your question, you can then simply use `xscale=-1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,blindtext}
\input{inkscape.tex}
\newsavebox\Ornament
\savebox\Ornament{\ornament{scale=1}}
\title{Table 1}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[below left] at ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north east)
{\usebox\Ornament};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[below left,xscale=-1] at ([xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north west)
{\usebox\Ornament};
\end{tikzpicture}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

A neat side-effect of this is that the coordinates are now symmetric `[xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1cm]` vs.[xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]`, and it is easy to avoid the overlap.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,blindtext}
\input{inkscape.tex}
\newsavebox\Ornament
\savebox\Ornament{\ornament{scale=1}}
\title{Table 1}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[below left] at ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north east)
{\usebox\Ornament};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[below left,xscale=-1] at ([xshift=0.25cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north west)
{\usebox\Ornament};
\end{tikzpicture}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps you. You can simply use `\reflectbox` along with `\rotatebox` to achieve your results

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz,blindtext}
    \input{inkscape.tex}
    \title{Table 1}
    \author{}
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[below left] at (current page.north east) {\ornament{scale=1}};
    \node[below left] at ([xshift=-10cm,yshift=0cm]current page.north east) {\reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{360}{\ornament{scale=1}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \blindtext
    \end{document}
```

You can play with `(x,y)` shifts to align as you want.

[image]

Comment: +1 for using `\reflectbox` and `\rotatebox`, but one should [really not nest tikzpictures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/121799).

Comment: @marmot New to `tikz` :D But will keep that in mind :)