# Chemmacros arrow in Tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemmacros

I want to use Chemmacros inside a tikz node but the arrow of the reaction is disturbed by the line before the node. My example work fine if I use `mhchem (\ce{A -> B})` instead of chemmacros. My MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- ++(1,1)
    node[anchor=west]{\ch{A -> B}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: strange_arrow]
Look and the end of the chemmacros arrow.

Comment: Not surprising since you are nesting tikzpictures. Please avoid putting chmemmacros into nodes of tikzpictures.

Answer (score 3):

I understand the problem. One solution:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\sbox{\mybox}{%
    \ch{2 H+ \aq{} + 2 e- -> H2 \gas}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- ++(1,1) node[anchor=west]
    {\usebox{\mybox}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

like is explain here [nesting tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul)

Comment: Yes, precisely. +1 Unfortunately your code in your question did not compile. Any chance that in more recent versions of `chemmacros` you need to do something in addition? Could you perhaps check that and, if it does not work with the updated version, append a solution for that case as well? Others with the same problem might find that useful...

Answer (score 2):

Is that ok, too?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- ++(1,1)
    node[anchor=west]{A \tikz[baseline=-.1cm]{\draw[>=stealth'](0,0)--+(.6,0)} B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I want to use chemmacros for my chemistry lessons. For example I want to put inside the node: \ch{2 H+ \aq{} + 2 e^- -> H2 \gas} or something more complex.

Comment: @jrivet: As `marmot` already mentioned you sholdn't use `chemmacros` in Ti*k*Z-nodes. Try to write it "by hand".

Comment: My example work fine if I use mhchem (\ce{A -> B}) instead of chemmacros. Can we get arround the difficulty?

Comment: @jrivet: If that does work (I didn't tried it since yet) that you can use it. But it's "safer" to do it by hand if there are any problems …

Comment: @current_user What is the difference between using a `tikzpicture` environment in a node, and using its inline equivalent `\tikz` in a node?