# How to put a reaction scheme from chemfig inside a TikZ picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, dimensions, shapes

I am trying to include a chemical reaction from the chemfig package into this picture of a cloud using the following code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node [cloud, draw,cloud puffs=10,cloud puff arc=120, aspect=2, inner ysep=2em] { 
\schemestart
A + B \arrow C
\schemestop
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I keep getting an error saying 
"Dimension too large". I have tried increasing the size of the cloud, using `\tiny` to reduce the size of the reaction, and nothing works, I keep getting the same error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Your code (snippet) nests `tikzpicture`s (because `chemfig` uses Ti*k*Z), which [should be avoided](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/121799). If you put the reaction in a `savebox`, there is no issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\newsavebox\ReactionBox
\sbox\ReactionBox{\schemestart
    A + B \arrow C
\schemestop
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \node [cloud, draw,cloud puffs=10,cloud puff arc=120, aspect=2, inner ysep=2em] 
    {\usebox\ReactionBox};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to go about putting another reaction underneath that one? I have tried making a `ReactionBoxTwo` and using  `\usebox\ReactionBox\vspace\usebox\ReactionBoxTwo` but it gives me an error.

Comment: @JohnMiller You could add `align=center` to the node options and then have `\usebox\ReactionBox\\ \usebox\ReactionBoxTwo` inside the curly brackets of the node. An arguably cleaner way is to put both reactions in one savebox, and use this in the node.

Comment: I put both reactions into a box and included the `align=center` option but still do not get the correct result. I will go ahead and make a separate question.