# Add non-bounding group to a molecule using chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I would like to obtain the following result:

[image]

I am workint with Overleaf and stuck in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{
-[:+30]  % C1
-[::-60] % C2
(-[::-60] -[::+45] NH_2)
-[::+45, 3]
}
\end{document}
```

I think that Overleaf doesn't load the latest version of `chemfig` package, since I tried to code the brackets with no success (and then I don't display the corresponding piece of code in the MWE). Is it possible to get the brackets by any other means? What about the *HCl floating above the NH2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Modified Answer:**

So the request is to not use `\polymerdelim`. I have come up
with a solution thanks to [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330411/167081) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455876/167081). The approach is to use a Ti*k*Z matrix that will have
only one cell (which will be the `chemfig`). The square brackets needed to be shifted inside which made
the positioning of the subscript `n` to be manually adjusted.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newsavebox\ourFormula
\sbox\ourFormula{
\chemfig[atom sep = 1.5em]{
    -[@{opening,0.75}:30]                       % Left opening bracket
    -[:+30]                                     % C1
    -[::-60]                                    % C2
    (
      -[::-60] -[::+45] NH_2                    % NH_2
     \raisebox{2em}{\hspace{-2em}$\bullet$ HCI} % HCI
    )
    -[::+45, 3] 
    -[@{closing,0.25}:+15]                      % Right closing bracket
  }
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    every left delimiter/.style={xshift=20pt},
    every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-20pt}
  ]
    \node (matrix) [left delimiter = {[}, right delimiter = {]}] {
      \usebox\ourFormula\\
    };
    \node [ xshift=48pt, yshift=-25pt] {$n$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Original Answer:**
The brackets can be easily obtained using the `\polymerdelim` marco (it also takes care of the right subscript `n`). Now, the challenge is to have the `•HCI` above `NH_2`. The way I did it is by using `\raisebox{vertical distance}{text}`. This made the `•HCI` to be positioned top right with respect to `NH_2`. The solution is to use `\hspace{negative distance}` to pull it over to the left and have them vertically aligned.

In the case you wanted to change the code, make sure to compile it **twice**.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
  \chemfig[atom sep = 1.5em]{
    -[@{opening,0.75}:30]                       % Left opening bracket
    -[:+30]                                     % C1
    -[::-60]                                    % C2
    (
      -[::-60] -[::+45] NH_2                    % NH_2
     \raisebox{2em}{\hspace{-2em}$\bullet$ HCI} % HCI
    )
    -[::+45, 3] 
    -[@{closing,0.25}:+15]                      % Right closing bracket
  }
  % Now, we can put everything inside the brackets and have n as our indice.
  \polymerdelim[height=30pt, delimiters={[]}, indice=n]{opening}{closing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @M.AlJumaily for the solution. I appreciate the way you placed the `HCI` group. However, as I mentioned in the question, I found out that Overleaf runs the version of `chemfig` previous to that which defines the macro `\polymerdelim`. Do you thing that there is another way of placing the brackets?

Comment: See the edit please.

Comment: Thank you very much, @M.AlJumaily!

Comment: You are very welcome @Brasil