# label shifting behavior in tikz vs tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, tikz-cd

I have a tikz picture that has labels, and the labels are in the correct place. However when I put the {tikzpicture} inside a {tikzcd} environment, the position of the labels shifts noticeably up, and they are no longer in the position I want. It would be easy enough to solve this by not using the {tikzcd} environment, but I want this picture to be part of a larger commuting diagram. So my question is,

How do I force the labels to stay in the same place when I place a {tikzpicture} inside a {tikzcd}?

I've included a stripped-down version of my code below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{fouriernc} % Fourier fonts instead of Computer Modern
\usepackage{PageSetup}      % general setup
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd}

% art style for graphs
\newcommand*{\bigradius}{2.7em} % radius of a circle-shaped graph
\newcommand*{\biggerradius}{6.0em} % radius of a really big circle-shaped graph
\newcommand*{\dist}{4em} % separation between nodes of a line-shaped graph
\newcommand*{\distshort}{3.25em} % separation between nodes of a line-shaped graph
\newcommand*{\labeloffset}{1em} % spacing between the edges and their labels
\newcommand*{\vertexlabeloffset}{1.5em} % spacing between the vertices and their labels
\newcommand*{\littleradius}{.4em} % radius of the vertices
\newcommand*{\straightpathwidth}{.17em} % width of a straight path (needs to be slightly thicker than a curved path)
\newcommand*{\curvedpathwidth}{.14em}

\begin{document}

    Correct:

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % the BIG circle
    \draw[black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (0,0) circle (\biggerradius);
    % vertices
    \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 90:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (120:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (150:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (180:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (210:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (240:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (270:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (300:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (330:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (  0:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 30:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 60:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    % labels
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 90:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_1$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 75:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_1$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 45:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_1$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 30:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_2$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 15:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_2$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (345:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_2$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (330:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_3$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (315:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_3$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (285:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_3$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (270:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_4$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (255:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_4$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (225:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_4$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (210:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_5$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (195:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_5$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (165:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_5$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (150:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_6$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (135:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_6$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (105:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_6$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    Incorrect:

    \begin{tikzcd}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        % the BIG circle
        \draw[black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (0,0) circle (\biggerradius);
        % vertices
        \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 90:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
        \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (120:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
        \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (150:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
        \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (180:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
        \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (210:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
        \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (240:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
        \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (270:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
        \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (300:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
        \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (330:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
        \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (  0:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
        \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 30:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
        \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 60:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
        % labels
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 90:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_1$};
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 75:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_1$};
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 45:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_1$};
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 30:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_2$};
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 15:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_2$};
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (345:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_2$};
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (330:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_3$};
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (315:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_3$};
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (285:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_3$};
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (270:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_4$};
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (255:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_4$};
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (225:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_4$};
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (210:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_5$};
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (195:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_5$};
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (165:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_5$};
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (150:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_6$};
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (135:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_6$};
        \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (105:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_6$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tikzcd}



\end{document}
```

It gives this result:

[image: The correct and incorrect behavior]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nesting a `tikzpicture` in another one is highly unrecommended.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I seem to be getting the same problem with the `subfigure` environment as well. Is there a good environment for positioning several pictures with arrows between them, or captions below, that doesn't come highly unrecommended?

Comment: Yes, subfigure is also deprecated, but the strange behavior is explained by nesting tikzpictures, as @egreg pointed out. If you [put the `ikzpicture` into as `\savebox`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul), the issues will disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! As pointed out by @egreg, and as is explained in more detail in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul), you should try to avoid nesting `tikzpictures`.

I am assuming now that you want to make the `tikzpicture` part of a commutative diagram. Then, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66028/121799), you may want to put the `tikzpicture` into a `\savebox`, such that is safe from the pgf keys of the ambient `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
% \usepackage{fouriernc} % Fourier fonts instead of Computer Modern
% \usepackage{PageSetup}      % general setup
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd}

% art style for graphs
\newcommand*{\bigradius}{2.7em} % radius of a circle-shaped graph
\newcommand*{\biggerradius}{6.0em} % radius of a really big circle-shaped graph
\newcommand*{\dist}{4em} % separation between nodes of a line-shaped graph
\newcommand*{\distshort}{3.25em} % separation between nodes of a line-shaped graph
\newcommand*{\labeloffset}{1em} % spacing between the edges and their labels
\newcommand*{\vertexlabeloffset}{1.5em} % spacing between the vertices and their labels
\newcommand*{\littleradius}{.4em} % radius of the vertices
\newcommand*{\straightpathwidth}{.17em} % width of a straight path (needs to be slightly thicker than a curved path)
\newcommand*{\curvedpathwidth}{.14em}

\newsavebox\IshouldNeveNestTikzPics
\begin{document}

    Correct:

\savebox\IshouldNeveNestTikzPics{\begin{tikzpicture}
    % the BIG circle
    \draw[black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (0,0) circle (\biggerradius);
    % vertices
    \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 90:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (120:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (150:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (180:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (210:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (240:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (270:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (300:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (330:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] (  0:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=black, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 30:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 60:\biggerradius) circle (\littleradius);
    % labels
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 90:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_1$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 75:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_1$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 45:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_1$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 30:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_2$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] ( 15:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_2$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (345:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_2$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (330:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_3$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (315:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_3$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (285:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_3$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (270:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_4$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (255:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_4$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (225:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_4$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (210:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_5$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (195:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_5$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (165:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_5$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (150:\biggerradius - \vertexlabeloffset) node {$P_6$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (135:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_6$};
    \draw[line width=\curvedpathwidth] (105:\biggerradius + \vertexlabeloffset) node {$B_6$};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\usebox\IshouldNeveNestTikzPics 

    Now correct:

    \begin{tikzcd}
        \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox\IshouldNeveNestTikzPics}}    \arrow[r] 
        \arrow[d]
            & \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox\IshouldNeveNestTikzPics}} \arrow[d]
        \\
        \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox\IshouldNeveNestTikzPics}}    \arrow[r] 
            & \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox\IshouldNeveNestTikzPics}}
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. The \vcenter and \hbox wrappers seem essential for the arrows to end up in the correct place, I'm not sure why but I'm very happy that the code actually works. Thank you!