# Connecting path to nodes contained in node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm drawing a block diagram with tikz, in which I have a node containing sub-nodes by means of nested tikzpictures.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{virtual}=[coordinate]

\tikzstyle{block}=[draw, inner sep=3pt]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=20pt]
    % nodes

    \node[virtual] (in) at (0mm,0mm) {};
    \node[block] (g) [right = of in] {G};

    \node[draw, anchor = east, inner xsep = 0, inner ysep = 5pt] (group) at ([xshift=100pt, yshift=50pt]g.west) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[virtual] (in) at (0,0) {};
        \node[block] (a) [right =  of in] {$A$};
        \node[block] (b) [above =  of a] {$B$};
        \node[draw,
              circle,
              anchor = center,
              inner sep = 1pt,
              xshift = 20pt,
              minimum size=3pt,
             ] (sum) at ($(a.east)!0.5!(b.east)$) {};
        \draw [->] (in.east) -- (a.west);
        \draw [->] (in.east|-b) -- (b.west);
        \draw [->] (a.east) -| (sum.south);
        \draw [->] (b.east) -| (sum.north);
        \draw [-] (sum.east) -- ([shift={(10pt,0)}]sum.east);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };


    %edges
    \draw[->] (g.east) -- ([shift={(100pt,0)}]g.east);
    \draw[->] ([shift={(10pt,0)}]g.east) |- (group.west); % <- I would like to connect to the in of block A

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

whose output is

[image: MWE output]

As I sketched with a red arrow in the picture, I would like to connect the signal coming up from the output of the node `g` to the node `group` in the position corresponding to the children-node `a`.

Is it possible to achieve this without the need of hard coding an yshift?

Comment: You should [*never* nest `tikzpicture`s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/121799).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an attempt to politely convince you that one should never nest `tikzpicture`s. This is not supported, and can lead to uncontrollable errors. And you do not need it. Just make the contents of the inner `tikzpicture` a `pic`, and use its coordinates as explained on p. 261 of the pgfmanual (version 3.1).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\begin{document}

\tikzset{virtual/.style={coordinate},
block/.style={draw, inner sep=3pt}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=20pt,
my subpicture/.pic={\begin{scope}[local bounding box=#1]
        \node[virtual] (in) at (0,0) {};
        \node[block] (a) [right =  of in] {$A$};
        \node[block] (b) [above =  of a] {$B$};
        \node[draw,
              circle,
              anchor = center,
              inner sep = 1pt,
              xshift = 20pt,
              minimum size=3pt,
             ] (sum) at ($(a.east)!0.5!(b.east)$) {};
        \draw [->] (in.east) -- (a.west);
        \draw [->] (in.east|-b) -- (b.west);
        \draw [->] (a.east) -| (sum.south);
        \draw [->] (b.east) -| (sum.north);
        \draw [-] (sum.east) -- ([shift={(10pt,0)}]sum.east);
    \end{scope}}]
    % nodes

    \node[virtual] (in) at (0mm,0mm) {};
    \node[block] (g) [right = of in] {G};

    \pic at ([xshift=33pt, yshift=50pt]g.west) (mypic) {my subpicture=group};
    \draw ([yshift=-5pt]group.south west) rectangle ([yshift=5pt]group.north east);


    %edges
    \draw[->] (g.east) -- ([shift={(100pt,0)}]g.east);
    \draw[->] ([shift={(10pt,0)}]g.east) |- (mypicin); % <- I would like to connect to the in of block A

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, got it. Just a pity that relatively positioning pictures is a pain. Consider having many pictures that needs to be aligned one with respect to the other in order to align "inputs" and "outputs", the only solution I found is to manually compute shifts, since the pic is positioned with respect its origin.

Comment: @mrk_brn The problem you are describing is usually solved by declaring a shape and playing with its anchors. For instance, `circuitikz` has tons of shapes which have such in an out anchors.