# tikz-cd nested tikzpicture wrong center anchor

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, nesting, anchor

I want to place a tikzpicture in a node/cell of a tikz-cd diagram and then paint some more stuff in the inner tikzpicture. However, it seems that the nesting messes up the `center` anchor.

Concretely: In the following MWE, why is the blue circle not properly in the center of the node? How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\newcommand{\boxedBWithAnchors}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(B.base)]
    \node[draw=black!20] (B) {B};
    \draw[draw=black!20] (B.south west) to (B.north east);
    \draw[draw=black!20] (B.north west) to (B.south east);
    \draw[draw=blue] (B.center) circle (1pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\,\boxedBWithAnchors
\begin{tikzcd}
\boxedBWithAnchors
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: Working anchor on the left, nested broken anchor on the right]

Comment: Nesting `tikzpicture`s is discouraged.

Comment: Saying that nesting is discouraged does not help, if you don't provide an alternative solution. (I am aware of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul )

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the `/tikz/commutative diagrams/every cell` style sets `shape=asymmetrical rectangle` which does not have the `center` anchor centered. The solution is to explicitly set `shape=rectangle` in the node again:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\newcommand{\boxedBWithAnchors}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(B.base)]
    \node[shape=rectangle,draw=black!20] (B) {B};
    \draw[draw=black!20] (B.south west) to (B.north east);
    \draw[draw=black!20] (B.north west) to (B.south east);
    \draw[draw=blue] (B.center) circle (1pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\,\boxedBWithAnchors
\begin{tikzcd}
\boxedBWithAnchors
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with egreg and definitely not nest `tikzpicture`s. It is also not needed. As you observed, one needs to also explicitly set the shape to `rectangle` if one wants to add this to single cells. (However, this can be done in the commutative diagram by adding `|[draw=black!20,outer sep=0pt,shape=rectangle]|` to the cell.) I used `\pgfkeys{cross circle/.code args={#1|#2}{...` in order to allow users to use the `/.list` key to loop over several cells. Note also that if you wanted the cross in the background, there would be a much simpler solution with `path picture`. (AFAIK `append after command` won't allow you to change the color for the circle.)

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\newcommand{\boxedBWithAnchors}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(B.base)]
    \node[draw=black!20] (B) {B};
    \draw[draw=black!20] (B.south west) to (B.north east);
    \draw[draw=black!20] (B.north west) to (B.south east);
    \draw[draw=blue] (B.center) circle (1pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\pgfkeys{cross circle/.code args={#1|#2}{
\draw[black!20] 
 (\tikzcdmatrixname-#1-#2.north west) -- (\tikzcdmatrixname-#1-#2.south east);
\draw[black!20] 
 (\tikzcdmatrixname-#1-#2.south west) -- (\tikzcdmatrixname-#1-#2.north east);
\draw[draw=blue] (\tikzcdmatrixname-#1-#2.center) circle (1pt);}}

\begin{document}
\boxedBWithAnchors
\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={\pgfkeys{cross circle={1|1}}
}]
|[draw=black!20,outer sep=0pt,shape=rectangle]|\text{B}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]