# Circle text inside tikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I am trying to circle some numbers inside tikz enviroment. I followed answers for this question: [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers)

And I used this solution, which work excellent inside normal text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}} 
 \begin{document}
 Numbers aligned with the text:  \circled{1} \circled{2} \circled{3} end.
 \end{document}
```

Unfortunately I encountered a problem. I want to create a few numbers in circle inside bigger tikz node. But it seems like new "nested" node inherits minimum width from "parent" node so the circle became very huge. Is there any way to work around this?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

I added MWE with my problem.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{big}=[draw,rectangle,rounded corners, fill=blue!20,minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2cm]

\node[big] (0) {First number = \circled{20},  Second number = \circled{20}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you should *never* nest `tikzpicture`s. You can store the inner ones in `\savebox`es and reuse them inside the outer tikzpicture, though, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/121799.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}} 
\newsavebox\SBoxA  
\newsavebox\SBoxB
\newsavebox\SBoxC
\begin{document}
\savebox\SBoxA{\circled{1}}\savebox\SBoxB{\circled{2}}\savebox\SBoxC{\circled{3}}%
Numbers aligned with the text:  \circled{1} \circled{2} \circled{3} end.

\circled{\usebox{\SBoxA} \usebox{\SBoxB} \usebox{\SBoxC}}
\end{document}` works.

Comment: Can you please post a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem in a `tikz` node.  Basic usage `\begin{tikzpicture}
     \node at (0,0) {\circled{1} \circled{2} \circled{3}};
 \end{tikzpicture}` seems to work, even though it is _not_ recommended.

Comment: @PeterGrill IMHO this is precisely the point: the things that go wrong when nesting `tikzpicture`s are hard to predict, which makes it hard for others to reproduce the issue without knowing what precisely the OP did. And once we know we will be able to to provide a workaround for that specific case, but I am pretty sure that we won't be able to find something that *always* works, so my recommendation is: *do not nest tikzpictures*.

Comment: I added MWE with my problem. It is little simplified, but I think it very well demonstrate what kind of problem happends.

Comment: For you _specific_ MWE, the `\node` option `big` is being inherited ny `\circled`, so if you change `\circled` to specify `minimum width=1em, minimum height=1em`, then you get the desired results. However, please note @marmot's comments.

Comment: @PeterGrill thank you, that actually solved my problem (at least temporarily).  I keep that comments in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want something like this?

[image]

I have modified the `\circled` command so that it now accepts a comma separated list. If the list contains only one entry then that entry is circled. If the list contains more than one entry then each entry is circled and then another circle is drawn around all of the circled numbers. So the right-hand entry above is the result of `\circled{1,2,3}`.

My macro avoids nesting `tikzpicture` environments by `remember`ing the number of items in the comma separated list. If the comma separated list contains more than than one entry then it uses the [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) `fit` library to draw the outside circle around all of the nodes. Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(1.base), 
      circ/.style={shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt}]
    \foreach \num [count=\c,remember=\c as \C (initially 0)] in {#1}{
      \node[circ] (\c) at (\c*3ex,0) {\num};% hack the node placement
    }                   % probably should use the positioning library
    \ifnum\C>1\node[circ,fit=(1)(\C)]{};\fi% circle multiple entries
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

  Numbers aligned with the text: \circled{1} \circled{2} 
  \circled{3} end and then we have \circled{1,2,3}

\end{document}
```

I have implicitly assumed that all of the circled entries in the comma separated list are all single characters. If this is not the case then it would be easy to modify the code above so that it uses the [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz)  `positioning` library to place the nodes next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your MWE can be solved by adding `minimum size=0pt` to the options of the node style in `\circled`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=0pt] (char) {#1};}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{big/.style={draw,rectangle,rounded corners, fill=blue!20,minimum
width=2cm, minimum height=2cm}}

\node[big] (0) {First number = \circled{20},  Second number = \circled{20}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

However, this is not a clean solution, and it may yield unpredictable results. A clean solution is to [put the inner `tikz` picture in a `\savebox`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/121799).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=0pt] (char) {#1};}} 
\newsavebox\SBoxA   
\begin{document}
\savebox\SBoxA{\circled{20}}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{big/.style={draw,rectangle,rounded corners, fill=blue!20,minimum
width=2cm, minimum height=2cm}}

\node[big] (0) {First number = \usebox\SBoxA,  Second number = \usebox\SBoxA};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will try to use savebox. So you suggest using tikset instead of tikzstyle?

Comment: @awarus Yes, `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.