# Edges of tree inside the state of a FSM are not displayed correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I am trying to draw a FSM (with \usetikzlibrary{automata}) that has trees as states. With my current code, the edges of trees inside states are only drawn incompletely. 
What may be causing this and how can I fix it?

My code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->]
    \node[state, inner sep=0] (q) {
        \begin{tikzpicture}[-]
            \node {$ \{ q_I, f, g, h, i \} $}
            child {node {$ \{ q_I \} $}}
            child {node {$ \{ f, g, h \} $}
            child {node {$ \{ g \} $}}
            child {node {$ \{ h \} $}}
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result:

[image: tree inside state]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE. You should never nest `tikzpicture`s.

Comment: @marmot Thanks! Could you explain that a little bit further? Obviously, the nesting produced a bad result in this case, but why is that? Where can I learn more about that?

Comment: Please see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/121799) why nesting `tikzpicture`s is a bad idea. Notice that by now this is even "more unsupported" than it used tp be, and future versions of Ti*k*Z may issue a warning if you do it, so don't. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this happens is that you are nesting `tikzpicture`s, which should be avoided. Here is a way to draw this figure without nesting `tikzpicture`s.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=tree]
            \node  {$ \{ q_I, f, g, h, i \} $}
            child {node {$ \{ q_I \} $}}
            child {node {$ \{ f, g, h \} $}
            child {node {$ \{ g \} $}}
            child {node {$ \{ h \} $}}
            };
 \end{scope}
 \node[state, inner sep=0,fit=(tree)] (q) {};           
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works for one state, but how can I combine it with positioning of several states?
If, e. g., I use `\node[state, below of=q3, inner sep=0, fit=(tree4)] (q4) {}; `, only the circle marking the state is moved, but not the tree that I want inside.

Comment: @flugdrachen You seem to have created a more complex example, so I do not know what `tree4` is. If you use `\begin{scope}[local bounding box=<something>] ... \end{scope}` and then `\node[circle,draw,fit=(<something>)] {};`, the circle will be drawn around the stuff that is inside the scope. If you add a complete example to your above question that explains what `tree4` stands for I can say more (or you could ask a separate question on that).

Comment: nvm, looking up the documentation for `fit` answered my question. The problem was that I was positioning the state around the box containing the tree with `fit`, then repositioning it with `below of` relative to another state, when instead I should have used `below of` on the tree box.

Comment: Nope, it did not work at last. I put it in a [new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490387/positioning-a-state-node-that-is-fitted-to-a-scope-inside-of-it-in-a-fsm).

Comment: @flugdrachen Yes, I saw, upvoted and answered it.