# Positioning a state node, that is fitted to a scope inside of it, in a FSM

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I am trying to draw a FSM in which some of the state nodes contain trees. To achieve this, I am using scopes as suggested in the answer to my [last question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490280/edges-of-tree-inside-the-state-of-a-fsm-are-not-displayed-correctly).

I want to position the state nodes relative to each other, in the hope of getting an image clearly aligned such as this:

[image: nice and tidy looking FSM]

But, if I position my state nodes relative to each other, after they are fitted to a scope containing a tree, the content of that scope is not moved with the sorrounding state node.

I tried positioning the scopes themselves like this: `\begin{scope}[-, right of=q1, local bounding box=tree2]`, but it does not seem to work and only causes the nodes to shift to odd positions.

In my current workaround (code pasted below), I am positioning the root node in each of the small trees inside the state nodes relative to another state node, but the result is crooked and ugly:

[image: crooked and ugly FSM]

What would be the correct/most pretty way to achieve alignment?

My full code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows, fit}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background, main, foreground}

\tikzset{
    ->, % makes the edges directed
    >=stealth', % makes the arrow heads bold
    node distance=3cm, % specifies the minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
    every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10, inner sep=0}, % sets the properties for each 'state' node
    every scope/.style={level distance = 0.8 cm},    
    initial text=$ $, % sets the text that appears on the start arrow
}

\begin{document}

% The problematic figure
\begin{figure} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state, initial] (q1) {$ \{ q_I \} $};

        \begin{scope}[-, local bounding box=tree2]
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}        
        \small
            \node[right of=q1] {$ \{ q_I, f \} $}
            child {node {$ \{ q_I \} $}};
        \end{pgfonlayer}        
        \end{scope}

        \node[state, fit=(tree2)] (q2) {};

        \node[state, right of=q2] (q3) {$ \{ f \} $!};


        \begin{scope}[-, local bounding box=tree4]
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \small
            \node[below of=q3]  {$ \{ q_I, f, g, h, i \} $}
            child {node {$ \{ q_I \} $}}
            child {node {$ \{ f, g, h \} $}
            child {node {$ \{ g \} $}}
            child {node {$ \{ h \} $}}
            };
         \end{pgfonlayer}
         \end{scope}

         \node[state, fit=(tree4)] (q4) {};  

         \node[state, accepting, left of=q4] (q5) {$q_5$};          

        \draw (q1) edge[loop above] node{0} (q1)
              (q1) edge[above] node{1} (q2)
              (q2) edge[loop above] node{1} (q2)
              (q2) edge[bend left, above] node{0} (q3)
              (q3) edge[bend left, below] node{0,1} (q2)
              (q3) edge[bend left, right] node{1} (q4)
              (q4) edge[above] node{0} (q5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

% How it should look like with "ordinary" state nodes
\begin{figure} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state, initial] (q1) {$ \{ q_I \} $};

        \node[state, right of=q1] (q2) {$q_2$};

        \node[state, right of=q2] (q3) {$ \{ f \} $!};

         \node[state, below of=q3] (q4) {$q_4$};  

         \node[state, accepting, left of=q4] (q5) {$q_5$};          

        \draw (q1) edge[loop above] node{0} (q1)
              (q1) edge[above] node{1} (q2)
              (q2) edge[loop above] node{1} (q2)
              (q2) edge[bend left, above] node{0} (q3)
              (q3) edge[bend left, below] node{0,1} (q2)
              (q3) edge[right] node{1} (q4)
              (q4) edge[above] node{0} (q5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works as expected in your code, but not as you want it to work. When you are saying

```
 \node[right of=q1] {$ \{ q_I, f \} $}
        child {node {$ \{ q_I \} $}};
```

this will place the *parent* node right of the `q1` node, and *not* the full tree. If you want to place the full tree right of `q1`, you could for instance [store it in a `\savebox`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66028/121799) such that it is safe to be nested.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows, fit}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background, main, foreground}

\tikzset{
    ->, % makes the edges directed
    >=stealth', % makes the arrow heads bold
    node distance=3cm, % specifies the minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
    every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10, inner sep=0}, % sets the properties for each 'state' node
    every scope/.style={level distance = 0.8 cm},    
    initial text=$ $, % sets the text that appears on the start arrow
}
\newsavebox\TreeOne
\newsavebox\TreeTwo
\begin{document}
\savebox{\TreeOne}{\tikz[font=\small,-]{\node {$ \{ q_I, f \} $}
            child {node {$ \{ q_I \} $}};}}
\savebox{\TreeTwo}{\tikz[font=\small,-]{\node  {$ \{ q_I, f, g, h, i \} $}
            child {node {$ \{ q_I \} $}}
            child {node {$ \{ f, g, h \} $}
            child {node {$ \{ g \} $}}
            child {node {$ \{ h \} $}}
            };}}
% The problematic figure
\begin{figure} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state, initial] (q1) {$ \{ q_I \} $};

        \node[state,right of=q1] (q2) {\usebox\TreeOne};

        \node[state, right of=q2] (q3) {$ \{ f \} $!};

         \node[state,below of=q3] (q4) {\usebox\TreeTwo};  

         \node[state, accepting, left of=q4] (q5) {$q_5$};          

        \draw (q1) edge[loop above] node{0} (q1)
              (q1) edge[above] node{1} (q2)
              (q2) edge[loop above] node{1} (q2)
              (q2) edge[bend left, above] node{0} (q3)
              (q3) edge[bend left, below] node{0,1} (q2)
              (q3) edge[bend left, right] node{1} (q4)
              (q4) edge[above] node{0} (q5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

% How it should look like with "ordinary" state nodes
\begin{figure} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state, initial] (q1) {$ \{ q_I \} $};

        \node[state, right of=q1] (q2) {$q_2$};

        \node[state, right of=q2] (q3) {$ \{ f \} $!};

         \node[state, below of=q3] (q4) {$q_4$};  

         \node[state, accepting, left of=q4] (q5) {$q_5$};          

        \draw (q1) edge[loop above] node{0} (q1)
              (q1) edge[above] node{1} (q2)
              (q2) edge[loop above] node{1} (q2)
              (q2) edge[bend left, above] node{0} (q3)
              (q3) edge[bend left, below] node{0,1} (q2)
              (q3) edge[right] node{1} (q4)
              (q4) edge[above] node{0} (q5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]