# Why \vspace{-\lineskip} removes space after tikz picture although it stands before the picture?

Tags: spacing, vspace

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node[inner sep=0,draw,text width=40mm]
      { \parbox{\hsize}
          { \parshape 4 0mm 40mm 5mm 35mm 10mm 30mm 15mm 25mm
            \fboxrule0.1pt
            \fboxsep0pt
            \fbox{hello world}\newline
            \fbox{hello world}\newline
            \fbox{hello world}
            \vspace{-\lineskip} % WHY AFTER THE PICTURE THAT FOLLOWS, NOT BEFORE?
            \begin{tikzpicture}
              \path node[draw,text width=24mm]
                { \parbox{\hsize}
                    { \begin{gather*}
                        2+2=4
                      \end{gather*}
                    }
                };
            \end{tikzpicture}
          }
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\savebox`es to properly nest `tikzpicture`s, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/121799.

Comment: why have you got those parboxes there at all?, you can remove both of them.

Comment: @bp2017 did you try?

Comment: you can use `\parshape` if you are in vertical mode, as you are in a tikz node if you specify the `text width` key. `standalone` class does not change that.

Comment: @bp2017 you are using `gather` here which is a vertical mode display environment, but you do not need `\parbox` basically if you use `text width` on a node it is a parbox already (actually it is a `minipage` but that is almost the same thing, mostly using the same code.)

Comment: the parbox are not just saving you worrying if you need it, as in an earlier question of yours you are nesting vertically centred boxes so throwing away all information about the top and bottom baselines of the text in the node, making positioning much harder.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I'm trying to grasp what you're saying. Do you mean `\parbox` inside a node throws away information about top and bottom baselines of text in the node?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I've tried using `text width` without `\parbox` for vertical-mode math just now. Vertical spacing of the equation becomes uneven on the bottom compared to when `\parbox` is used. With `\parbox` the equation's top and bottom spacing is even (without `\parbox` it's not). I guess that's one of the reasons I use `\parbox`. (I have to think of other reasons, nothing comes to mind yet.) But it's interesting that `\parbox` makes information about vertical spacing to be lost inside the node.

Comment: @bp2017 yes if course, a parbox only has a single reference point, by default in its vertical centre, so there is only one baseline as far as the node can see. If you put a paragraph directly in the node then it can be aligned on the top or bottom baseline or the vertical center, that was why you had to use `\strut` in an earlier question

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, specifying `text width` doesn't make `\parshape` work inside the node. (I am posting the code in the next comment.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node
      [ draw=blue,
        inner sep=0pt,
        line width=1.5pt,
        text width=40mm
      ]
      { \parshape 4 0mm 40mm 5mm 35mm 10mm 30mm 15mm 25mm
        \fboxrule0.1pt
        \fboxsep0pt
        \fbox{hello world}\newline
        \fbox{hello world}\newline
        \fbox{hello world}
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Comment: @bp2017 hard to tell with comment formatting but you are probably missing a blank line at the end of the paragraph before the `}` I get indented boxes when I added  linebreaks to your code from the comment, not really tikz, you would get the same from any group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third line is split because it doesn't fit. But every `\vspace` material in a paragraph will be inserted *after* the line in which the command happens to fall (it uses `\vadjust`).

Just add `\newline`. And don't overcomplicate things.

```latex
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\fbox{%
  \parbox{40mm}{
    \parshape 4 0mm 40mm 5mm 35mm 10mm 30mm 15mm 25mm
      \fbox{hello world}\newline
      \fbox{hello world}\newline
      \fbox{hello world}
      \vspace{-\lineskip}\newline
      \fbox{%
        \parbox{24mm}{
          \begin{gather*}
            2+2=4
          \end{gather*}
        }%
      }
   }
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It is unrelated to tikz, if you use `\vspace` in horizontal mode it is inserted after linebreaking.

```
aaa\vspace{1cm}bbb
```

adds the space after bbb

You possibly wanted to have blank line before the `\vspace` so that the space is added in vertical mode at the point it appears in the source.