# Putting a plot inside a tab

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pgfplots

How to put the graph of this interval plot inside the box denoted graph1.
Here are the code for the tables and the code for the interval plot. By the way can we change the code to have the first column in red and the first line in green. [image]
[image]
Table's code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand*\head[1]{\textbf{#1}}
% The table environment:
\newenvironment{matrixtable}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[matrix of nodes/.style={
    execute at begin cell=\node\bgroup\strut,
    execute at end cell=\egroup;}]
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,top color=white!20,
    bottom color=white!80,draw=white,
    nodes={draw,top color=white!10,bottom color=blue!15,
    draw,inner sep=2pt,minimum height=3.1ex},
    column sep=1ex,row sep=0.6ex,inner sep=2ex,
    rounded corners,column 1/.style={minimum width=#1},
    column 2/.style={minimum width=#2},
    column 3/.style={minimum width=#3}]}
   %
{;\end{tikzpicture}}
%


\begin{center}
\begin{frame}

\begin{matrixtable}{7cm}{3cm}{7cm}{
  \head{Intervalle}   & \head{Inégalité} & \head{Représentation graphique}  \\
  $[a~;~b]\text{ fermé }$ & $ a\le x\le b$  & graph 1 \\
  $[a~;~b[\text{ fermé à  gauche, ouvert à  droite }$ & $a\le x<b $   & graph2 \\
  $]a~;~b]\text{ ouvert à gauche, fermé à droite }$ & $a<x\le b$      & graph3\\ 
   $]a~;+\infty [$ & $x>a$ &  graph4 \\
  $[a~;+\infty [$ & $x\ge a$ &  graph5  \\
 $]-\infty;b~ [$ & $x< b$ &  graph6    \\
  $]-\infty;b~ ]$ & $x\le b$ &  graph7     \\
  }
\end{matrixtable}

\end{frame}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

here's the code for the interval plot

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[stealth-stealth] (-6,0) node[below]{$-\infty$} -- (6,0) node[below]{$\infty$};
 \draw[very thick,blue,{Bracket[reversed,width=1.2em]}-{Bracket[width=1.2em]}] (-3.05,0) -- (2,0) node[pos=-1/40,above]{$a$} node[pos=29/30,above]{$b$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your MWE compilable. Where are defined `\head`?

Comment: @Zarko Corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [proper way to nest `tikzpicture`s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/121799) is to use `\saveboxes`. I also rotate your table as it is too wide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing}
\newsavebox\Plot
\sbox\Plot{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
 \draw[stealth-stealth] (-6,0) node[below]{$-\infty$} -- (6,0) node[below]{$\infty$};
 \draw[very thick,blue,{Bracket[reversed,width=1.2em]}-{Bracket[width=1.2em]}]
 (-3.05,0) -- (2,0) node[pos=-1/40,above=0.5em]{$a$} node[pos=29/30,above=0.5em]{$b$};
 \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\head[1]{\textbf{#1}}
% The table environment:
\newenvironment{matrixtable}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[matrix of nodes/.style={
    execute at begin cell=\node\bgroup\strut,
    execute at end cell=\egroup;}]
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,top color=white!20,
    bottom color=white!80,draw=white,
    nodes={draw,top color=white!10,bottom color=blue!15,
    draw,inner sep=2pt,minimum height=3.1ex},
    column sep=1ex,row sep=0.6ex,inner sep=2ex,
    rounded corners,column 1/.style={minimum width=#1},
    column 2/.style={minimum width=#2},
    column 3/.style={minimum width=#3}]}
   %
{;\end{tikzpicture}}
%


\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{frame}

\begin{matrixtable}{7cm}{3cm}{7cm}{
  \head{Intervalle}   & \head{Inégalité} & \head{Représentation graphique}  \\
  $[a~;~b]\text{ fermé }$ & $ a\le x\le b$  & \usebox\Plot \\
  $[a~;~b[\text{ fermé à  gauche, ouvert à  droite }$ & $a\le x<b $   & graph2 \\
  $]a~;~b]\text{ ouvert à gauche, fermé à droite }$ & $a<x\le b$      & graph3\\ 
   $]a~;+\infty [$ & $x>a$ &  graph4 \\
  $[a~;+\infty [$ & $x\ge a$ &  graph5  \\
 $]-\infty;b~ [$ & $x< b$ &  graph6    \\
  $]-\infty;b~ ]$ & $x\le b$ &  graph7     \\
  }
\end{matrixtable}

\end{frame}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can easily change the colors of rows or columns by saying something like `column 1/.style={nodes={...}}`, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing}
\newsavebox\Plot
\sbox\Plot{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
 \draw[stealth-stealth] (-6,0) node[below]{$-\infty$} -- (6,0) node[below]{$\infty$};
 \draw[very thick,blue,{Bracket[reversed,width=1.2em]}-{Bracket[width=1.2em]}]
 (-3.05,0) -- (2,0) node[pos=-1/40,above=0.5em]{$a$} node[pos=29/30,above=0.5em]{$b$};
 \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\head[1]{\textbf{#1}}
% The table environment:
\newenvironment{matrixtable}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[matrix of nodes/.style={
    execute at begin cell=\node\bgroup\strut,
    execute at end cell=\egroup;}]
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,top color=white!20,
    bottom color=white!80,draw=white,
    nodes={draw,top color=white!10,bottom color=blue!15,
    draw,inner sep=2pt,minimum height=3.1ex},
    column sep=1ex,row sep=0.6ex,inner sep=2ex,
    rounded corners,column 1/.style={minimum width=#1,nodes={top
    color=white!10,bottom color=red!15}},
    row 1/.style={nodes={top
    color=white!10,bottom color=red!15}},
    column 2/.style={minimum width=#2},
    column 3/.style={minimum width=#3}]}
   %
{;\end{tikzpicture}}
%


\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{frame}

\begin{matrixtable}{7cm}{3cm}{7cm}{
  \head{Intervalle}   & \head{Inégalité} & \head{Représentation graphique}  \\
  $[a~;~b]\text{ fermé }$ & $ a\le x\le b$  & \usebox\Plot \\
  $[a~;~b[\text{ fermé à  gauche, ouvert à  droite }$ & $a\le x<b $   & graph2 \\
  $]a~;~b]\text{ ouvert à gauche, fermé à droite }$ & $a<x\le b$      & graph3\\ 
   $]a~;+\infty [$ & $x>a$ &  graph4 \\
  $[a~;+\infty [$ & $x\ge a$ &  graph5  \\
 $]-\infty;b~ [$ & $x< b$ &  graph6    \\
  $]-\infty;b~ ]$ & $x\le b$ &  graph7     \\
  }
\end{matrixtable}

\end{frame}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @\marmot. Can we use different colours for the first column and the first line?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @manooooh  How please?

Comment: Wait for marmot's help.

Comment: @HAMIDINESOUMARE I added an example how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

As supplement to @marmot answer:

- for drawing "plot" is defined new command `Interval` with two parameters by which is possible to determine all kind of intervals
- environment `matrixtable` is replaced with style `matrixtable.sty` defined by `\tikzset`
- defined are four new save boxes, each for one combination of the `Interval`'s command parameters
- frame is replaced by `matrix` border

**Edit:**

code is adapted according to your "answer" requirements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, matrix, positioning}

\newcommand\IntervalB[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[Stealth-Stealth] (-2.5,0) node[below]{$-\infty$} -- (2.5,0) node[below]{$\infty$};
    \draw[very thick,blue,{Bracket[#1,width=1.2em]}-{Bracket[#2,width=1.2em]}]
        (-1.5,0) node[above=4pt]{$a$} -- (1.5,0) node[above=4pt]{$b$};
\end{tikzpicture}
               }
\newcommand\IntervalR[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[Stealth-Stealth] (-2.5,0) node[below]{$-\infty$} -- (2.5,0) node[below]{$\infty$};
\ifnum#1=-1
    \draw[very thick,red,{Bracket[#2,width=1.2em]}-Stealth]
        (-1.5,0) node[above=4pt]{$a$} -- (2.5,0);
\else
    \draw[very thick,red,Stealth-{Bracket[#2,width=1.2em]}]
        (-2.5,0) -- (1.5,0)  node[above=4pt]{$b$};
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}
               }
\tikzset{matrixtable/.style = {%
    matrix of nodes,
     nodes={draw=blue, rounded corners=1ex,
            minimum height=3ex, inner ysep=1pt,
            top color=white,
            bottom color=blue!15,
            anchor=center},
    column sep=1ex,
    row sep=0.6ex,
    column 1/.style={text width=62mm,nodes={draw=red,bottom color=red!15}},
    column 2/.style={text width=17mm},
    column 3/.style={text width=56mm},
    row 1/.style={nodes={draw=red,bottom color=red!15}},
    draw, inner sep=1.5mm}}

\newsavebox\plotA
\newsavebox\plotB
\newsavebox\plotC
\sbox\plotA{\IntervalB{}{}}
\sbox\plotB{\IntervalB{}{reversed}}
\sbox\plotC{\IntervalB{reversed}{}}
%
\newsavebox\plotRA
\newsavebox\plotRB
\newsavebox\plotRC
\newsavebox\plotRD
\sbox\plotRA{\IntervalR{-1}{reversed}}
\sbox\plotRB{\IntervalR{-1}{}}
\sbox\plotRC{\IntervalR{1}{reversed}}
\sbox\plotRD{\IntervalR{1}{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrixtable]
{
Intervalle      & Inégalité         & Représentation graphique  \\
$]a~;~b]$ fermé & $ a\le x\le b$    &   \usebox\plotA           \\
$[a~;~b[$ fermé à  gauche, ouvert à  droite
                & $a\le x<b $       &   \usebox\plotB           \\
$]a~;~b]$ ouvert à gauche, fermé à droite
                & $a<x\le b$        &   \usebox\plotC           \\
$]a~;+\infty [$ & $x>a$             &   \usebox\plotRA           \\
$[a~;+\infty [$ & $x\ge a$          &   \usebox\plotRB           \\
$]-\infty;b~ [$ & $x< b$            &   \usebox\plotRC           \\
$]-\infty;b~ ]$ & $x\le b$          &   \usebox\plotRD           \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: see my answer $\quad$

Comment: Thank you @Zarko

Answer (score 0):

This picture cannot fit in my post. So I’m writing this as an ‘’answer’’. It should be an edit to @Zarko’s answer.
\
The intervals are not the same, it should look like in this picture. I’ve done it using @marmot’s answer. [image]

Comment: I didn't bother with correctness of plots. IN my answer are just variation of four orientation of brackets. Also in your question is presented only one ... If the drawing those plots is problem to you, I suggest you to ask new question. For red one I would define new command, similarly as is done for blue intervals, but with correct arrow heads.

Comment: see edited answer.