# Tikz command disrupted inside tikz macro

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw some diagrams in tikz for which the labels have trees as indices. I render these trees as tikz diagrams, too. Even with simple diagrams, such as an arrow between two nodes, if a tree is inserted as label of the arrow, then the result is very unpleasant.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\TreeW}
{
    \tikz
    {
        \draw[-] (-.1,.2) -- (0,0) -- (.1,.2); \draw[-] (0,0) -- (0,.2);
    }
}

\newcommand{\TreeV}
{%
    {%
        \mathchoice%
        {\tikz \draw[-]                   (-.1,.2) -- (0,0) -- (.1,.2);}%
        {\tikz \draw[-]                   (-.1,.2) -- (0,0) -- (.1,.2);}%
        {\tikz \draw[-] [thin, scale=.75] (-.1,.2) -- (0,0) -- (.1,.2);}%
        {\tikz \draw[-] [thin, scale= .5] (-.1,.2) -- (0,0) -- (.1,.2);}%
    }
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
 \node (s0) at (180:2) {$\TreeW_{\TreeV}$};
 \node (s1) at (0,0) {$\TreeV$};
 \draw[->] [shorten >=10pt, shorten <=10pt] (s0) --
 node [above, near start] {$\TreeW$} node [below, near end] {\hbox{$\TreeV$}} (s1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the following result.

[image]

I tried to search a bit for similar problems, but I haven't encountered any; although it is most likely a well-known issue.

Comment: Instead of defining a command, you can define a `pic`. See TikZ manual 3.1.4 on page 259.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that it nests `tikzpicture`s. [This is to be avoided](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377). The standard way to avoid the problems is to use `\savebox`es. (A `pic` won't work here since you use `\mathchoice` and from your previous question I take that the reason why you do not use `tikz-cd` for this diagram is that you want to keep the example minimal. The following works also with `tikz-cd`.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newsavebox\TreeWbox
\sbox\TreeWbox{\tikz{%
        \draw[-] (-.1,.2) -- (0,0) -- (.1,.2); \draw[-] (0,0) -- (0,.2);
    }}
\newsavebox\TreeVbox
\sbox\TreeVbox{\tikz \draw[-]  (-.1,.2) -- (0,0) -- (.1,.2);}

\begin{document}    
\newcommand{\TreeW}{\usebox\TreeWbox}
\newcommand{\TreeV}{\mathchoice{\usebox\TreeVbox}{%
\usebox\TreeVbox}{%
\scalebox{0.8}{\usebox\TreeVbox}}{%
\scalebox{0.6}{\usebox\TreeVbox}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
 \node (s0) at (180:2) {$\TreeW_{\TreeV}$};
 \node (s1) at (0,0) {$\TreeV$};
 \draw[->] [shorten >=10pt, shorten <=10pt] (s0) --
 node [above, near start] {$\TreeW$} node [below, near end] {\hbox{$\TreeV$}} (s1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your code works perfectly as long as you add the `tips=never` option that prevents you from drawing the arrow and don't forget to delete the `[-]` option you placed to delete this arrow without success. 
The arrow drawing options are explained on page 188 of the TikZ 3.1.4b manual.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

%\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\TreeW}
{
    \tikz[tips=never]
    {
        \draw[] (-.1,.2) -- (0,0) -- (.1,.2); \draw[] (0,0) -- (0,.2);
    }
}

\newcommand{\TreeV}
{%
    {%
        \mathchoice%
        {\tikz[tips=never] \draw                   (-.1,.2) -- (0,0) -- (.1,.2);}%
        {\tikz[tips=never] \draw                   (-.1,.2) -- (0,0) -- (.1,.2);}%
        {\tikz[tips=never] \draw [thin, scale=.75] (-.1,.2) -- (0,0) -- (.1,.2);}%
        {\tikz[tips=never] \draw [thin, scale= .5] (-.1,.2) -- (0,0) -- (.1,.2);}%
    }
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
 \node (s0) at (180:2) {$\TreeW_{\TreeV}$};
 \node (s1) at (0,0) {$\TreeV$};
 \draw[->] [shorten >=10pt, shorten <=10pt
 ] (s0) --
 (s1) node [above, near start] {$\TreeW$} node [below, near end] {\hbox{$\TreeV$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```