# Tikz Forest coloring and edge label positions

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, forest

Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (tree)
        {
            \begin{forest}
                for tree = {circle, draw, minimum width = 2.25em}
                    [\textcolor{red}{$S$}
                        [$A$, edge label = {node [midway, above left, font = \scriptsize] {\textcolor{red}{$1$}}}
                            [$B$, edge label = {node [midway, above left, font = \scriptsize] {$4$}}
                                [$D_1$, edge label = {node [midway, left, font = \scriptsize] {$7$}}
                                    [$G_1$, edge label = {node [midway, left, font = \scriptsize] {$10$}}]
                                ]
                            ]
                            [$C$, edge label = {node [midway, above right, font = \scriptsize] {$2$}}
                                [$D_2$, edge label = {node [midway, above left, font = \scriptsize] {$3$}}
                                    [$G_2$, edge label = {node [midway, left, font = \scriptsize] {$6$}}]
                                ]
                                [$G_3$, edge label = {node [midway, above right, font = \scriptsize] {$4$}}]
                            ]
                        ]
                        [$G_4$, edge label = {node [midway, above right, font = \scriptsize] {$12$}}]
                   ]
        \end{forest}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Here are a couple of questions concerning this:

1. I would like to color the boundary of nodes (circles) red, as well as make some of the edges red. Is there a way to do so?
2. For the edge labels, as for horizontal and vertical positions as in `node[midway, right]` or `node[midway, above]`, this is ok for vertical and horizontal edges, respectively, but for **slanted** edges, as they can take on **any** angle, I would like to label the edges such that they are of the **same distance as the horizontal and vertical labels**, but in **a perpendicular direction** to the slanted edges. How does one code it up?
3. How to make the edge lengths longer? For all the edges? For some edges?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should *never* put a forest tree in a node of a `tikzpicture`.

Comment: Hmm what I am trying to do is to illustrate some search algorithms (e.g. Depth First Search, Breadth First Search, A* Search, etc.) so I want to have the trees but in a sequence of colors. What's wrong with putting a forest tree in a node of a `tikzpicture`?

Comment: Then put it in a `\savebox` and the `\savebox` in a node.

Comment: So would this work:
`\begin{document} \savebox{forest1}{%tree content} \begin[tikzpicture} \node(tree){\usebox{forest}} \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}` Also, do you know how one can color the tree's nodes and edges as well as label the edges like what I want for slanted edges?

Comment: almost. `\newsavebox\SomethingWithBackslash \savebox\SomethingWithBackslash{<tree>} \begin[tikzpicture} \node(tree){\usebox\SomethingWithBackslash}; \end{tikzpicture}.`

Comment: Ok. Can you post a sample solution showing two copies of the same tree but of different colors on nodes and edges as well as the the edge labels on slanted edges based on what I want for my results?

Answer (score 3):

Well this is one forest with red circle nodes (`draw=red`), a larger `l sep` (`l sep+=2em`) and circle-shaped edge labels to ensure a universal distance. I also color one edge blue. You can add `s sep+=1em` and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{eln/.style={midway, font = \scriptsize,circle,inner sep=2pt}}
\begin{forest}
for tree = {circle, 
    draw=red, %<-added =red
    minimum width = 2.25em,
    l sep+=2em
}
    [\textcolor{red}{$S$}
        [$A$, edge label = {node [above left,eln] {\textcolor{red}{$1$}}}
            [$B$, edge label = {node [above left,eln] {$4$}}
                [$D_1$, edge label = {node [left,eln] {$7$}}
                    [$G_1$, edge label = {node [left,eln] {$10$}}]
                ]
            ]
            [$C$, edge label = {node [above right,eln] {$2$}},edge=blue%<-blue edge
                [$D_2$, edge label = {node [above left,eln] {$3$}}
                    [$G_2$, edge label = {node [left,eln] {$6$}}]
                ]
                [$G_3$, edge label = {node [above right,eln] {$4$}}]
            ]
        ]
        [$G_4$, edge label = {node [above right,eln] {$12$}}]
   ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or color just a specific node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{eln/.style={midway, font = \scriptsize,circle,inner sep=2pt}}
\begin{forest}
for tree = {circle, 
    draw,%
    minimum width = 2.25em,
    l sep+=2em
}
    [\textcolor{red}{$S$}
        [$A$, edge label = {node [above left,eln] {\textcolor{red}{$1$}}}
            [$B$, edge label = {node [above left,eln] {$4$}}
                [$D_1$, edge label = {node [left,eln] {$7$}}
                    [$G_1$, edge label = {node [left,eln] {$10$}}]
                ]
            ]
            [$C$,draw=red, edge label = {node [above right,eln] {$2$}},edge=blue%<-blue edge
                [$D_2$, edge label = {node [above left,eln] {$3$}}
                    [$G_2$, edge label = {node [left,eln] {$6$}}]
                ]
                [$G_3$, edge label = {node [above right,eln] {$4$}}]
            ]
        ]
        [$G_4$, edge label = {node [above right,eln] {$12$}}]
   ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want to color all the nodes red. How can I color some select nodes red and others blue?

Comment: Just add `draw=red` for this one and remove  `draw=red`  from `for tree`.

Comment: What does `\tikzset{eln/.style={midway, font = \scriptsize,circle,inner sep=2pt}}` do? Finally, what could go wrong if I include the forest tree inside a node in `tikzpicture`?

Comment: It defines a style and spares you from repeating the same thing over and over.

Comment: Ok, that’s for the first question. What about the second question? What could be some problems that can arise in the case of what I did originally?

Comment: @Superman nesting  TikZ picture is not supported and will fail. If you search for "nesting tikzpicture" you have a lot of hits, but for example look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul