# Vertically center text in a table (tabular) contained in a circuitikz document

Tags: tables, circuitikz

In a document, I would like to vertically align cell text. The only problem is that my array is contained in a begin {circuitikz} so the few tests I was able to do (with begin {center} in particular) don't work.

Can you help me ?

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone} 
usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, european, straightvoltages, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin {document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\node at (0,0) 
{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Type & Composant & Code & Image résultant\\
\hline
\multirow{7}{*}{Alimentation} & pile & to[battery1] & \begin{circuitikz} \draw (0,0) to[battery1] (2,0);\end{circuitikz} \\
\cline{2-4}
 & source de courant & to[isource] & \begin{circuitikz} \draw (0,0) to[isource] (2,0);\end{circuitikz} \\
 \cline{2-4}
 & source de tension & to[vsource] & \begin{circuitikz} \draw (0,0) to[vsource] (2,0);\end{circuitikz} \\
 \cline{2-4}
 & source sinusoidale & to[sV] ou to[vsourcesin] & \begin{circuitikz} \draw (0,0) to[sV] (2,0);\end{circuitikz} \\
 \cline{2-4}
 & source sinusoidale & to[sV] ou to[vsourcesin] & \begin{circuitikz} \draw (0,0) to[sV] (2,0);\end{circuitikz} \\
 \cline{2-4}
 & source créneau & to[sqV] ou to[vsourcesquare] & \begin{circuitikz} \draw (0,0) to[sqV] (2,0);\end{circuitikz} \\
 \cline{2-4}
 & source triangulaire & to[tV] ou to[vsourcetri] & \begin{circuitikz} \draw (0,0) to[tV] (2,0);\end{circuitikz} \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
};
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tikzset{ baseline=(current bounding box.center)}` should help to vertically center the contents of the second column with respect to the third column.

Comment: Please make your MWE compilable. It contain many errors.

Comment: You shouldn't nest `tikzpicture` and/or `circuitikz` environments.

Comment: Nesting `tikzpicture` (and circuitikz are the same as them) is going to explode before or later: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul

Comment: @Rmano :  Ah, I'm not an expert: I must have found it hard to understand what should be done to allow me to mix tabular (or similar) and circuitikz?

Comment: You can put a `tabular` in a node, but you can't put a `tikzpicture` in that tabular. The form of having tabulated material in a `tikzpicure` is to use a `matrix` element. In this case, @Zarko answer is the correct one in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder, why you insert this table in TikZ node?.  Removing it and adjusting images  baseline gives:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\usepackage[siunitx, european, straightvoltages, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\makegapedcells
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={baseline=-0.5ex}}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Type & Composant & Code & Image résultant\\
    \hline
\multirow{16}{*}{Alimentation} 
    & pile & to[battery1] & \begin{circuitikz}
                            \draw (0,0) to[battery1] (2,0);
                            \end{circuitikz} \\
    \cline{2-4}
    & source de courant   
        & to[isource]     & \begin{circuitikz}
                            \draw (0,0) to[isource] (2,0);
                            \end{circuitikz} \\
    \cline{2-4}
    & source de tension 
        & to[vsource]     & \begin{circuitikz}
                            \draw (0,0) to[vsource] (2,0);
                            \end{circuitikz} \\
    \cline{2-4}
    & source sinusoidale 
        & to[sV] ou to[vsourcesin] 
                          & \begin{circuitikz}
                            \draw (0,0) to[sV] (2,0);
                            \end{circuitikz} \\
    \cline{2-4}
    & source sinusoidale 
        & to[sV] ou to[vsourcesin] 
                          & \begin{circuitikz}
                            \draw (0,0) to[sV] (2,0);
                            \end{circuitikz} \\
    \cline{2-4}
    & source créneau 
        & to[sqV] ou to[vsourcesquare] 
                          & \begin{circuitikz}
                            \draw (0,0) to[sqV] (2,0);
                            \end{circuitikz} \\
    \cline{2-4}
    & source triangulaire 
        & to[tV] ou to[vsourcetri] 
                          & \begin{circuitikz}
                            \draw (0,0) to[tV] (2,0);
                            \end{circuitikz} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice, this is that I want !
Can you explain me why, in the multirow command, it is indicated 16 ? I counted the cells but i can't find a number that matches 16

Comment: @Nicolas, you should count number of text rows which can be fir in these cells (on the such way are measured multirow cell height). Due to contained image and added vertical space, their sum of height is approximately of 16 text lines.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the precision