# Can't include an image in a folded cube in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I'm trying to create a papercraft cube, and can't seem to get an image in one of the faces. I have tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193555/crop-jpeg-into-circular-tikz-node)

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm,paperheight=8cm,margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary {folding}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3.3]
  \pic [
    folding line length=6mm,
    transform shape,
    rotate=40,
    face 1= { \node{ Pax }; },
    face 2= { \node{ Tibi }; },
    face 3= { \node{\tiny Marce}; },
    face 4= { \node{\tiny Evangelista}; },
    face 5= { \node{\tiny Meus}; }
    face 6= { \node[path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center){ \includegraphics{dogos.jpg}} }] }
  ]
  { cube folding };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I have tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580810/inserting-multiple-images-to-a-tikz-paper-folding-diagram) too, with the two versions; it does not work either.

It simply creates an empty face (it also creates two pages, I don't really know why). I have also tried simply including `\includegraphics` into the face, but that does not work either. The only difference with the two examples seems to be that it's rotated and the scale, but I don't think that is the thing. The image is in .png and .jpg format, too.

Comment: Why the extra node? `face 6= {\node{\includegraphics{dogos.jpg}};}`? By the way, you're missing the `;`, the `{}` from the outer node` and a `,` between face 5 and face 6. The extra page comes from the picture being to big.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel that was suggested by the answers I've mentioned, also tried without it. Will check the comma, though.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel the comma and semicolon did it... partially. Now the whole cube has disappeared

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel changing the size and your comma and semicolon managed to make it. It still deletes part of the folding lines, but that's not big deal. `    face 6= {  \node[anchor=center] {\includegraphics[width=0.9cm]{dogos} };}` Can you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a `,` between `face 5` and `face 6` which is the reason why face 6 was empty.

I'd only use one node here where the image is scaled to the `folding line length`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm,paperheight=8cm,margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {folding}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
  \pic [
    folding line length=6mm,
    transform shape,
    rotate=40,
    face 1= { \node{ Pax }; },
    face 2= { \node{ Tibi }; },
    face 3= { \node{\tiny Marce}; },
    face 4= { \node{\tiny Evangelista}; },
    face 5= { \node{\tiny Meus}; }, % ← ,
    face 6= { \node{\includegraphics[width=6mm]{example-image} }; } % ← ;
  ]
  { cube folding };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]