# externalize crashes with TikZ-within-TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

In the MWE below, there is a custom arrow defined as a separate drawing using `\tikz`. The arrow is used as an edge node so that it can be sloped automatically.

I am also using the TikZ `external` package because this is part of a book-length project with many TikZ figures.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\newcommand{\myarrow}{\tikz{\draw[->] (0,0)--(10pt,0)}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \node[draw] (1) at (0,0) {};
        \node[draw] (2) at (1,1) {};
            
        \draw (1) to[edge node={node [sloped,above] {\myarrow}}] (2);
        
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If I try to compile the MWE as-is, I get an error message:

```
/mwe.tex:18: Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escap
e -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "mwe-figure0" "\def\tikzextern
alrealjob{mwe}\input{mwe}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'mwe-figure0
' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled 
system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is a
lso named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed
? Error messages can be found in 'mwe-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll t
ry to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.18        \end{tikzpicture}
                        
? 
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./mwe.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on mwe.pdf (1 page, 8538 bytes).
SyncTeX written on mwe.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on mwe.log.
```

If I comment out the `\tikzexternalize` line, it compiles fine:

[image]

And if I comment out the `\draw (1) ...` line, it compiles fine too. Any suggestions?

Comment: Never nest tikzpicture in tikzpicture. This make problems without externalizing.

Comment: Oh. I didn't realize that was a problem. Is there a particular reason it's a bad idea, or just that not all features are supported if you nest them?

Comment: You may bi satisfied with the following solution: `\draw (1) to[edge node={node [sloped,above] {$\longrightarrow$}}] (2);`

Comment: Sometimes nesting works, mostly it doesn't.  It has to do with conflicting global parameters.  The general solution is to put one tikzpicture into a savebox and use \usebox, but for externalize it might be better to use a file and \includegraphics.  (Or just use standalone instead.)

Comment: OK, thanks, I didn't know that. I will use @Zarko's suggestion for the arrow.

Comment: You can use a `sloped` `pic` for the sloped arrow. This avoids nesting and gives you all the arrow heads and line styles you want.

Comment: @user241266 can you clarify? What is a `sloped` `pic`?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul for a quite lengthy discussion about tikzpictures nesting

Answer (score 2):

Since this does not fit into a comment. It has already been pointed out that one should not nest `tikzpicture`s. It is also not necessary, Ti*k*Z has a tool for what you are doing: `pic`s. These can be sloped, too, and endowed with parameters (via pgf keys).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/my arrow/.style={code={
    \tikzset{my arrow/.cd,#1}
    \draw[my arrow/arrow] 
    (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my arrow/length}/2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my arrow/y})
    --(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my arrow/length}/2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my arrow/y});}},
    my arrow/.cd,
    arrow/.style={->},length/.initial=10pt,y/.initial={0pt}]

    \node[draw] (1) at (0,0) {};
    \node[draw] (2) at (1,1) {};

    \draw (1) to pic[sloped]{my arrow={y=4pt}} (2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works but I'm having a little trouble parsing all the syntax. If I don't need the `pic` to size dynamically (i.e., I don't need it to take an argument), how would I simplify your code?