# Access nodes in tikzpicture within tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

Got the following from a student. The last line is trying to access the nodes inside of nodes `A` and `B`, but it doesn't do so. Can this approach succeed?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
  inner/.style={circle,draw=black!50,fill=white!20,thick,inner sep=3pt},
  outer/.style={draw=black,fill=black!20,thick,inner sep=10pt}
  ]
  \node[outer,draw=black] (A) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[inner, state] (a) {$a$};
      \node[inner, state] (b) [below =of a] {$b$};
      \node[inner, state] (c) [below =of b] {$c$};
      \node[inner, state] (d) [below =of c] {$d$};
      \node[inner, state] (e) [below =of d] {$e$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
  \node[outer,draw=black,right=of A] (B) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[inner, state] (f) {$f$};
      \node[inner, state] (g) [below =of f] {$g$};
      \node[inner, state] (h) [below =of g] {$h$};
      \node[inner, state] (i) [below =of h] {$i$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
  \draw[very thick,orange,-] (a) -- (i);
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul: nesting tikzpictures is not supported, everything can happen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to use of `matrix` library at drawing your image:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,
                positioning}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
M/.style = {matrix of math nodes,%
            nodes={circle, draw=gray, thick,
            minimum size=2em, text depth=0.25ex,
            inner sep=0pt},
            row sep=2em,
            draw, thin
             }
                        ]
\matrix (m) [M]
{
a \\    b \\    c \\    d \\    e\\
};
\matrix (n) [M, right=of m]
{
f \\    g \\    h \\    i \\
};
\draw[very thick,orange] (m-1-1) -- (n-4-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `matrix` and judicious use of `\\`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, %fixed by PROF
  inner/.style={circle,draw=black!50,fill=white!20,thick,inner sep=3pt},
  outer/.style={draw=black,fill=black!20,thick,inner sep=10pt}
  ]
  \node[matrix,draw=black] (A) {
      \node[inner, state] (a) {$a$};
      \node[inner, state] (b) [below =of a] {$b$};
      \node[inner, state] (c) [below =of b] {$c$};
      \node[inner, state] (d) [below =of c] {$d$};
      \node[inner, state] (e) [below =of d] {$e$};\\
  };
  \node[matrix,draw=black,right=of A] (B) {
      \node[inner, state] (f) {$f$};
      \node[inner, state] (g) [below =of f] {$g$};
      \node[inner, state] (h) [below =of g] {$h$};
      \node[inner, state] (i) [below =of h] {$i$};\\
  };
  \draw[very thick,orange,-] (a) -- (i);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Could delete this, but maybe it will help someone

Comment: This is a possible, nice, smart and, in particular, correct way of doing this, apart from using scopes, chains etc. Yet, to be honest, this solution is great mainly because the original attempt, which nests `tikzpicture`s, is basically the opposite of great.