# How to embed tikzpicture inside tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to embed the following plot:

[image]

inside this backup diagram at the place where I've written "hi":

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Do you know of any way I could do this with Tikz? Thanks, your help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Here's what I have cobbled together so far, I used the `intersections` library for it:

```
% Tree like backup diagram
\tikzset{
state_node/.style={circle, draw=black, scale=1.2},
action_node/.style={circle, fill=black, scale=0.68},
}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=18mm/#1}]
\node[action_node] (a) {}
  child {node[state_node] (s) {}
    child {node[action_node] (a1) {}}
    child {node[action_node] (a2) {}}
    child {node[action_node] (a3) {}}
  };
% I would like the graph to go here
\node[below] at (a3.south) {hi};

\draw [->] (a) edge (s);
\draw [name path=edge1, ->] (s) to (a1);
\draw [name path=edge2, ->] (s) to (a2);
\draw [name path=edge3, ->] (s) to (a3);

\path[name path=c] (s) circle (1);
\draw[name intersections={of=edge1 and c, by=intersection1},
      name intersections={of=edge3 and c, by=intersection2},
-, shorten >=0pt]
(intersection1) to[bend right] (intersection2);


\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Q-learning backup diagram}
\end{figure}

% Miniature graphs that I would like to embed above
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=0, xmax=1,
    ymin=0, ymax=1,
    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty
  ]

  \addplot table {
    0.8   0
    0.8 0.3
    0.3 0.8
    0   0.8
  };

  \addplot table[only marks] {
    0.3 0.36
    0.8 0.3
    0.3 0.8
  };

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the TeX code you have so far ... Then we have not to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Thank you and sure thing!

Comment: Generally speaking, it's not recommended to embed tikzpicture into tikzpicture. And in the present case, it's very hard to figure out what output you expect exactly. Maybe with a sketch?

Comment: What you have provided is insufficient.  There are many unresolved tikz labels, for example  `e1`.  Also, you haven't specified what documentclass you are using, or what tikzlibraries may be required.

Comment: @SebGlav I've added the sketch.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul - you shouldn't nest tikzpictures it's not supported and sometimes works but often it doesn't...

Comment: @Rmano, it looks like "nested" was the proper way of phrasing it. Thanks for the link I'll see if I can find a solution there.

Comment: Move the `axis` environment to inside the first `tikzpicture`, and add `at={(x,y)}` to the `axis` options, where `x` and `y` are appropriate coordinates.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., it is a bit fiddly but the result is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. Should I mark this question as resolved?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in comments.