# Any idea to export this circuitikz to PDF?

Tags: pdf, circuitikz, export, tikz-circuit-lib

Any idea to export this circuitikz to PDF? 
I used tikzpicture but it cut part of image on the right. That is probably due to the incompability between
tikz and circuitikz. 
Note that the PDF size should be the same as the image size, so please don't suggest compile and export the whole PDF page.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize 


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) node (N5){}
    to [short,o-](2,0) 
    to[short,*-](4,0)
    to[D](4,2)
    to[D](4,4)
    to[short,-*](2,4) node (N1){}
    to[short,-o](0,4) node (O){}; 
    \draw (4,0) 
    to[short,*-](8,0) 
    to[D](8,2)
    to[D](8,4)
    to[short,-*](4,4);
    \draw (2,0)
    to[Tnpn,n=q2](2,2) node(N2){}
    to[Tnpn,n=q1](2,4);
    \draw (8,0)
    to[short,*-](10,0) node(N4){}
    to[Tnpn,n=q4,mirror](10,2)
    to[Tnpn,n=q3,mirror](10,4)
    to[short,-*](8,4);
    \draw
    (q1.B) to[short,-o](1,3) node[left]{$Q_1$}
    (q2.B) to[short,-o](1,1) node[left]{$Q_2$}
    (q3.B) to[short,-o](11,3) node[right]{$Q_3$}
    (q4.B) to[short,-o](11,1) node[right]{$Q_4$};
    \draw (2,2) to[short,*-*](4,2) to[Telmech=M](8,2) to[short,*-*](10,2) node(N3){};
    % adding current
    \begin{scope}[on background layer, very thick,decoration = {
        markings,
        mark = at position 0.05 with {\arrow{>}}}
    ] 
    \draw[line width = 3pt, red!40, postaction = {decorate}] (O.north)
    -- node[above, red]{$i$} (N1.north east) |- (N3.north west) |-
    (N5.north); 
    \end{scope}
    % adding voltage
    \draw[line width = 3pt, red!40, ->] (N5) to[out = 150, in = 210]
    (O) node[left, red]{$V$};
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Circutikz **is** a tikzpicture, so you are putting a tikzpicture inside another tikzpicture and they do not nest. Also, \centering inside a tikzpicture does nothing.

Comment: @JohnKormylo  I see, thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IMHO the problem is the resulting bounding box of the `tikzpicture` not an incompatibility. You could fix this using `\useasboundingbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}% circuitikz is also a tikzpicture
%  \begin{circuitikz}% but only tikzpicture is externalized.
    \draw (0,0) node (N5){}
    to [short,o-](2,0) 
    to[short,*-](4,0)
    to[D](4,2)
    to[D](4,4)
    to[short,-*](2,4) node (N1){}
    to[short,-o](0,4) node (O){}; 
    \draw (4,0) 
    to[short,*-](8,0) 
    to[D](8,2)
    to[D](8,4)
    to[short,-*](4,4);
    \draw (2,0)
    to[Tnpn,n=q2](2,2) node(N2){}
    to[Tnpn,n=q1](2,4);
    \draw (8,0)
    to[short,*-](10,0) node(N4){}
    to[Tnpn,n=q4,mirror](10,2)
    to[Tnpn,n=q3,mirror](10,4)
    to[short,-*](8,4);
    \draw
    (q1.B) to[short,-o](1,3) node[left]{$Q_1$}
    (q2.B) to[short,-o](1,1) node[left]{$Q_2$}
    (q3.B) to[short,-o](11,3) node[right]{$Q_3$}
    (q4.B) to[short,-o](11,1) node[right]{$Q_4$};
    \draw (2,2) to[short,*-*](4,2) to[Telmech=M](8,2) to[short,*-*](10,2) node(N3){};
    % adding current
    \begin{scope}[on background layer, very thick,decoration = {
        markings,
        mark = at position 0.05 with {\arrow{>}}}
    ] 
    \draw[line width = 3pt, red!40, postaction = {decorate}] (O.north)
    -- node[above, red]{$i$} (N1.north east) |- (N3.north west) |-
    (N5.north); 
    \end{scope}
    % adding voltage
    \draw[line width = 3pt, red!40, ->] (N5) to[out = 150, in = 210]
    (O) node[left, red]{$V$};
  \useasboundingbox(0,0) rectangle (12,4);% not needed any longer after commenting circuitikz but sometimes useful
%  \end{circuitikz}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, if you need a PDF with the picture only, a very simple solution would be to use class `standalone` and correct it using option `border`:

```
\documentclass[border={-15mm 3mm 16mm 3mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
%\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) node (N5){}
    to [short,o-](2,0) 
    to[short,*-](4,0)
    to[D](4,2)
    to[D](4,4)
    to[short,-*](2,4) node (N1){}
    to[short,-o](0,4) node (O){}; 
    \draw (4,0) 
    to[short,*-](8,0) 
    to[D](8,2)
    to[D](8,4)
    to[short,-*](4,4);
    \draw (2,0)
    to[Tnpn,n=q2](2,2) node(N2){}
    to[Tnpn,n=q1](2,4);
    \draw (8,0)
    to[short,*-](10,0) node(N4){}
    to[Tnpn,n=q4,mirror](10,2)
    to[Tnpn,n=q3,mirror](10,4)
    to[short,-*](8,4);
    \draw
    (q1.B) to[short,-o](1,3) node[left]{$Q_1$}
    (q2.B) to[short,-o](1,1) node[left]{$Q_2$}
    (q3.B) to[short,-o](11,3) node[right]{$Q_3$}
    (q4.B) to[short,-o](11,1) node[right]{$Q_4$};
    \draw (2,2) to[short,*-*](4,2) to[Telmech=M](8,2) to[short,*-*](10,2) node(N3){};
    % adding current
    \begin{scope}[on background layer, very thick,decoration = {
        markings,
        mark = at position 0.05 with {\arrow{>}}}
    ] 
    \draw[line width = 3pt, red!40, postaction = {decorate}] (O.north)
    -- node[above, red]{$i$} (N1.north east) |- (N3.north west) |-
    (N5.north); 
    \end{scope}
    % adding voltage
    \draw[line width = 3pt, red!40, ->] (N5) to[out = 150, in = 210]
    (O) node[left, red]{$V$};
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: result of using standalone]

Note: With option `tikz` class `standalone` does also provide to generate several PDF pages in the same PDF, one for each `tikzpicture`. To change the options from page to page, you can use `\standaloneconfig`, e.g.,

```
\standaloneconfig{border={3mm 3mm 3mm 3mm}}
```

before the corresponding `tikzpicture`.

An even simpler suggestion would be to use `\documentclass[landscape]{article}` and `\pagestyle{empty}` and afterwards use `pdfcrop` to cut of the large white margins from the generated PDF. With

```
pdfcrop --margins 10pt original.pdf
```

the resulting `original-crop.pdf` would be almost the same as shown above.

Comment: What if I want to export many pictures in the same tex file?

Comment: @internet Please, if you have an additional question, ask an additional questions instead of using a comment. Short comment: Load `standalone` with option `tikz` to make one page per `tikzimage`. And use `\standaloneconfig` to change other options, e.g. `\standaloneconfig{border={3mm 3mm 3mm 3mm}}` to change the margin to 3mm around the next `tikzpicuture`. See the `standalone` manual for more information.

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't intend to ask for multiple figures when I posted the question.  Now I decided to make one file for each figure as people seem to agree that it's better.

Answer (score 6):

Although the proposed way to have an independent PDF [proposed by @cabohah](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667699/38080) is arguably the correct/best way,
the main error here is that [you are nesting `tikzpictures`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul). Instead of

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{circuitikz}
...
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

use just

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

`circuitikz` is just an alias for `tikzpicture`; it works most of the time but *not* when externalize is involved. This is mentioned in the manual:

[image]

(FAQ section). Although I admit it is a bit hidden; I am pondering to change all the `\begin{circuitikz}...\end{circuitikz}` in the manual...

*Also*, notice that `\centering` inside a `tikzpicture` is doing nothing but harm. Probably you are mixing the concept of `figure` and `tikzpicture`?

Comment: This is a nice as well.

Comment: What would you recommend to export figures to PDFs? For example, I have three figures in the same tex and I want to export to three PDFs? The answer given by cabohah is nice but now I realize that making each tex file for one figure is too much and hard to keep the style consistent.

Comment: Well, you *can* use `tikzexternakize`, just call all environment `tikzpicture`. But a well organized set of independent files is almost unbeatable for flexibility. Just keep the styles in a common file, use a standard skeleton for the files, and with the help of a Makefile you can even automate it (I never tried that myself, though, because I use `latexmk` to compile and I am not sure/never spent the time to learn how o do it.).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I'll keep them separately then.

Comment: For small projects, you can just prepare files with just the circuit and include them as source, to avoid complexity. It's true that if you have tens of pictures the compilation can slow down a lot (the circuitikz manual, which is monolithic, needs 4+ minutes on a Ryzhen9 with plenty of RAM...)

Comment: That is one reason, another reason is that I have to make one project on Overleaf for each figure as they allow one main file to be compiled as far as I know.