# Diverging arrow in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I need to create a reaction scheme where a single molecule is hit by light generating 2 states each evolving to one state(refer to picture)
Since merge don't work in reverse (connect one molecule to 2 )

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage{floatrow}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{cmbright}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,     allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{float}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, arrows.meta}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{figure}
                \schemestart
                \chemfig{R_1-[:40](=[:90]O)-[:-40]R_2}
                \arrow[->]{$h\nu$}
                \chemleft[\chemfig{R_1-[:40](=[:90]O)-[:-40]R_2}\chemright{]^{S_1}}\arrow{->[ISC]}[-90] \chemleft[\chemfig{R_1-[:40](=[:90]O)-[:-40]R_2}\chemright{]^{T_1}} \merge(c1)(c2)--()\chemfig{R_1-[:40]\Charge{[.radius=1.5pt,.style={draw=gray}] 0 =\.[{.style={draw=none,fill=black}}]}{C} =[:90]O}  \+ \Charge{[.radius=1.5pt,.style={draw=gray}]
                180 =\.[{.style={draw=none,fill=black}}]}{R_2}
                \schemestop
                \caption{ My Caption}
            
            \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image: sample image]
Also how to align the last 2 molecules, the one on the right with dots.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error I came up with the following solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
\setchemfig{bond style={line width=1pt},atom sep=2.1em}

\usepackage[body={17.0cm,26cm},top=2.0cm,left=2.0cm]{geometry}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox\keto
\sbox\keto{\chemfig{C(=[:90]O) (-[:-140]R_1) (-[:-40]R_2)}} % needed to save inner box from outer box parameters in TikZ
\centering
\schemestart
        \chemleft[\chemfig{R_1-[:40](=[:90]O)-[:-40]R_2}\chemright{]^{S_1}}
    \arrow{->[ISC]}[-90]
        \chemleft[\chemfig{R_1-[:40](=[:90]O)-[:-40]R_2}\chemright{]^{T_1}}
     \merge(c1)(c2)--()
        \chemfig{\charge{[circle,.radius=1.5pt,.style={draw=gray,fill=gray}] 0 =\.}{C}(-[:-140]R_1) =[:90]O} 
    \+ 
        \charge{[circle,.radius=1.5pt,.style={draw=gray,fill=gray}]180 =\.}{R_2}
    \chemmove{
        \node[] at (-10.8,-0.15) {\usebox\keto};
        \draw[thick,red,-{stealth},shorten >= 2pt] (-9.5,0) -- node[above,rotate=50,yshift=2mm] {$h\nu$} (c1.west);
        \draw[thick,red,-{stealth},shorten >= 2pt] (-9.5,0) -- node[below,rotate=-50,yshift=-2mm] {$h\nu$} (c2.west);
        }
\schemestop 
    
\end{document}
```

Since `chemfig` relies on `TikZ` you can use tikz commands in the `\chemmove` environment. In this case I had to start with the two states and the last part of the reaction scheme. The first part had to be entered using `\chemmove`. Special care must be taken with placing a `\chemfig` molecule in a TikZ node. See [Proper nesting of tikzpicture environments: Reset all PGF values to their defaults](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul) .

You may need to play around a bit with the parameters in the `\chemmove` part of this scheme. *Note:* because the origin of the
first `\chemfig{}` entry lies to the right, you need to use negative values in the x-coordinate, which can lead to dropping of the page. Hence the `\centering` command.

**Edit**
Changing the `\chemmove` part in

```
\chemmove{
    \node[] at (-10.8,0) {\usebox\keto};
    \draw[-{stealth},shorten >= 2pt] (-8.5,0) |- (c1.west);
    \draw[-{stealth},shorten >= 2pt] (-8.5,0) |- (c2.west);
    \draw[-] (-9.5,0.2) -- node[above, yshift=2mm] {$h\nu$} (-8.5,0.2);
}
```

will give the same arrows on the left side as the merge on the right side and as is proposed by ChocoDuck.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The arrow also works backwards, use \arrow{<-}

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a reverse arrow merge using the "chemfig" and "arrow" commands. Just adjust the parameters to get the "reverse merge" you need.

```
\documentclass[margin={2mm 2mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{-[0,1,,,red,thick](-[2,1,,,red,thick]@{z})(-[6,1,,,red,thick]@{x})}
\arrow(@{z}--){->[$h\nu$]}[00,1,shorten <=-10pt,red,thick]
\arrow(@{x}--){->[$h\nu$]}[00,1,shorten <=-10pt,red,thick]
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{(-[:210]R_2)(-[:330]R_1)=[2]O}
    \arrow(a--)[,1.5,,,draw=none]
    \subscheme{
        \charge{30:4pt=$\mathrm{S}_1$}{\chemleft{[}\chemfig{(-[:210]R_2)(-[:330]R_1)=[2]O}\chemright{]}}
        \arrow(b--c){->[*{0}ISC]}[-90,1.5]
        \charge{30:4pt=$\mathrm{T}_1$}{\chemleft[\chemfig{(-[:210]R_2)(-[:330]R_1)=[2]O}\chemright{]}}
    }
    \arrow(--d)[,1.5,,,draw=none]
    \chemfig{(-[:210]R_2)(-[:330,0.1,,,draw=none]\charge{330:-1pt=\.\,}{})=[2]O}
    \+
    \chemfig{\charge{90:1pt=\.\,}{R}_1}
    \schemestop
    \chemmove{
        \draw[thick,shorten >=10pt] (a.east) -- ++(1,0) |- (b.west);
        \draw[thick,shorten >=10pt] (a.east) -- ++(1,0) |- (c.west);
        \draw[-,thick,shorten >=15pt,shorten <=8pt] (b.east) -- ++(1.3,0) |- (d.west);
        \draw[thick,shorten >=10pt,shorten <=8pt] (c.east) -- ++(1.3,0) |- (d.west);
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]