# tikz-feynman diagram is cut off the page in standalone document

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, tikz-feynman

When I use the `tikz-feynman` package to draw a Feynman diagram, the PDF output is so strange. It looks like it has been cut. I thought it was because the real center point of the Tikz picture is not what it seems.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    \begin{feynman}
        \feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
            i1[particle=\(\phi\)] -- [scalar, edge label=\(p_2\)] a -- [anti fermion,edge label=\(p_1\)] i2[particle=$\psi(\lambda_1)$],
            a -- [fermion,momentum=\(p_1+p_2\)] b,
            f1[particle=\(\phi\)] -- [scalar, edge label=\(q_1\)] b -- [fermion,edge label=\(q_2\)] f2[particle=\(\psi(\lambda^\prime_1)\)]
};  
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I try to change the settings of `standalone`, like

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}
```

This time it reveals the whole diagram, but it's still not centered?
[image]

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Removing the `tikzpicture` and `feynman` environments (the stuff with `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}`) does the trick. Alternatively, you can keep the environments, then change `\feynmandiagram` into a simple `\diagram` to get your desired output. Both methods are shown in the code below.

```tex
%!TeX program = LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}

% Both of these methods produce the same output
% Choose the one you like better

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Method 1
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  i1[particle=\(\phi\)] -- [scalar, edge label=\(p_2\)] a -- [anti fermion,edge label=\(p_1\)] i2[particle=$\psi(\lambda_1)$],
  a -- [fermion,momentum=\(p_1+p_2\)] b,
  f1[particle=\(\phi\)] -- [scalar, edge label=\(q_1\)] b -- [fermion, edge label=\(q_2\)] f2[particle=\(\psi(\lambda^\prime_1)\)]
};

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Method 2
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
  \diagram [horizontal=a to b] {
    i1[particle=\(\phi\)] -- [scalar, edge label=\(p_2\)] a -- [anti fermion,edge label=\(p_1\)] i2[particle=$\psi(\lambda_1)$],
    a -- [fermion,momentum=\(p_1+p_2\)] b,
    f1[particle=\(\phi\)] -- [scalar, edge label=\(q_1\)] b -- [fermion,edge label=\(q_2\)] f2[particle=\(\psi(\lambda^\prime_1)\)]
  };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can see your output fits into a single standalone page now:

[image: Feynman diagram with the correction to make the entire diagram appear on the page]

So, why didn't your original code work the way it was supposed to? It turns out, the definition of the `\feynmandiagram` macro creates both a `tikzpicture` and `feynman` environment. However, because your `\feynmandiagram` was already inside these environments, LaTeX was essentially putting a set of `tikzpicture` and `feynman` environment inside *another set of* `tikzpicture` and `feynman` diagrams. This probably explains why you saw the center of the diagram not being where it seemed—that was the center point of the *inner* tikzpicture, but the standalone package was shaping the page based on the box size of the *outer* tikzpicture.

Comment: thank you! It helps a lot!

Comment: Never put a tikzpicture inside another tikzpicture.  The results can be odd.

Comment: @JohnKormylo your comment helped to set me on the right track for finding why my code worked and the OP's code didn't; thanks! I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Meng.G I'm glad you found this helpful! If you're satisfied with this solution, I'd be grateful if you could mark my answer as Accepted by clicking the check mark (below the voting buttons).

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul