Intersections package not locating the intersection of an arc and a line segment in TikZ
The "intersections" package of TikZ is not properly locating the intersection of the blue circular arc drawn about point C and the angle bisector of $\angle{C}$.
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}


\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}




\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1/2]

\path (0,0) coordinate (B) (8,0) coordinate (C) (11/2,9) coordinate (A);
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0] at ($(A) +(0,0.15)$){$A$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at (0,-0.15){$B$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(C) +(0,-0.15)$){$C$};



%The angle mark at A drawn. It is marked with "|".
\draw[draw=orange] let \n1={-acos(5/sqrt(349))}, \n2={acos(11/sqrt(445))}, \n3={-180+\n2} in ($(A)!1.2cm!(C)$) arc (\n1:\n3:1.2);
\path[fill=orange!50, fill opacity=0.5, draw=orange] let \n1={-acos(5/sqrt(349))}, \n2={acos(11/sqrt(445))}, \n3={-180+\n2} in (A) -- ($(A)!1.2cm!(C)$) arc (\n1:\n3:1.2) -- cycle;


%The angle mark at B is drawn. It is marked as "||".
\draw[name path=arc_to_mark_angle_at_B, draw=green] let \n1={acos(11/sqrt(445))} in (1,0) arc (0:\n1:1);
\path[fill=green!50, fill opacity=0.75, draw=green] let \n1={acos(11/sqrt(445))} in (B) -- (1,0) arc (0:\n1:1) -- cycle;


%The angle mark at C is drawn. It is marked as "|||".
\path[fill=blue!50, fill opacity=0.5, draw opacity=1] let \n1={acos(5/sqrt(349))}, \n2={180-\n1} in (C) -- ($(C)!0.75cm!(B)$) arc (180:\n2:0.75) -- cycle;
\draw[name path=arc_to_mark_angle_at_C, draw=blue] let \n1={acos(5/sqrt(349))}, \n2={180-\n1} in ($(C)!0.75cm!(B)$) arc (180:\n2:0.75);
\draw[name path=the_angle_bisector_of_C, loosely dashed] let \n1={acos(5/sqrt(349))}, \n2={180-\n1}, \n3={180-1/2*\n1} in (C) -- ($(C) +(\n3:3)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=arc_to_mark_angle_at_C and the_angle_bisector_of_C, by={intersection_with_angle_bisector_at_C}}];
\draw[fill=green] (intersection_with_angle_bisector_at_C) circle (3pt);


\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\vskip0.25in



\end{document}


How do you calculate the angle bisector at B? You don’t show this in your code example.

I asked the wrong question. I edited my post. I am now asking "Why isn't the intersections package locating the intersection of the arc about C and the angle bisector of $\angle{C}$?"

If you don't use an intermediate coordinate, then this works \draw [name intersections={of=arc_to_mark_angle_at_C and the_angle_bisector_of_C, by={intersection_with_angle_bisector_at_C}}]     [fill=green] (intersection_with_angle_bisector_at_C) circle (3pt);. So, must be some issue with the naming of the \coordinate.  Another option which requires less change to your code, is to replace \coordinate ... with \path ....

what makes you think this ought to work with \coordinate rather than \path? (@PeterGrill? not sure if you were saying it should or not.)

@Peter Grill  Your first suggestion did put a green dot at the midpoint of the arc. It is bizarre that the intermediate step of naming the coordinate would cause TikZ to miscalculate.

@Peter Grill  Also, replacing "\coordinate[name intersections={of= ..." with "\path coordinate[name intersections={of= ..." gave me the same wrong location of the green dot.

@user143462 name intersections isn't an option which applies to a coordinate. It applies to (pairs of) paths. I don't see why it should be surprising that you can't calculate the intersections of paths while positioning coordinates.

I suspect it's a scoping issue. \coordinate[options] is equivalent to \path coordinate[options] meaning that the options are executed in the scope of the coordinate, not the path. It is not equivalent to \path[options] coordinate. In short, don't use a complicated path command where you don't need it.

If you remove the scale=1/2 from your tikzpicture environment then you will see that the intersection is in the right place. Alternatively, drawing a path from the origin to the intersection point and through twice as far ends at the desired intersection:
\draw
(0,0) -- (intersection_with_angle_bisector_at_C) --
($(0,0)!2!(intersection_with_angle_bisector_at_C)$);

When you have \coordinate[options] then this expands to \path coordinate[options] (and thence to \path node[shape=coordinate,options]).
Deep in the code intersections={of=...} is \path[..] coordinate (...); which sets the location of the coordinate found at an intersection (either named via the by= option or with a default name). So \coordinate[intersections...] is a nested node which is generally regarded as a Bad Thing.
In particular, the options for a node are not executed until quite a lot of the node structure has been set up, part of which is removing a lot of the data that TikZ has set up during the picture, such as the coordinate transformation in place. This is because during the node contents then TikZ wants to pretend that it isn't there. It does, however, keep track of that information so that it can restore it later.
When the node/coordinate location is saved then TikZ needs to store the transformation that was in place so that it can correctly calculate the location.
So what is happening here is that the scale=1/2 is getting applied twice due to the nesting of the coordinates.
I haven't looked at exactly where this is getting applied twice, because nesting nodes is known not to be a good idea, and there's a very, very simple change to make it work as noted in the comments: replace the \coordinate by \path, as in
\path[name intersections={of=arc_to_mark_angle_at_C and the_angle_bisector_of_C, by={intersection_with_angle_bisector_at_C}}];

Even better, as pointed out by @Qrrbrbirlbel in the comments, since that command isn't doing any actual path construction itself then it can just be in a \tikzset:
\tikzset{name intersections={of=arc_to_mark_angle_at_C and the_angle_bisector_of_C, by={intersection_with_angle_bisector_at_C}}}


https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66037/86 on nesting tikzpictures is not quite the right answer to link to for nesting nodes, but does illustrate the issues with nesting in TikZ.

I deleted my answer. I thought that nesting nodes was generally safe, as opposed to nesting tikzpictures. isn't a matrix of nodes basically  nesting nodes?

@cfr In a matrix then the nodes aren't nested in terms of the code, they're just nested in terms of their positions.

You don't even need \path. Just \tikzset{name intersections={…}} does it. It's not necessary to do this on a path. (I don't see an advantage besides maybe a scoping of the total option.) I don't see why it scales twice, though I suspect the \coordinates for the by option is doing something. Though, I would also scale by using the x and y option first before I use scale.

@Qrrbrbirlbel even without the by option then there's a nested coordinate: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/ab7c1475b4acbaafd0f3ba8d166489d32fb0fe0e/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryintersections.code.tex#L108 . Scaling by setting x and y fixes the intersecting issue, but messes up so much else of the diagram that it's not worth trying here. There's so much that is hardcoded that shouldn't be that I didn't want to pull on any threads and so looked for the minimum changes to make it work.

@AndrewStacey Yeah, but that's using reset cm but you're right, it also happens without the by. :| I just played around, it already is in the wrong place when using \pgftext[at=\pgfpointintersectionsolution{\pgfmathcounter}]{XXX} outside of the internal path, outside of any internal coordinate.  Anyway, yeah, just use \tikzset.

@Qrrbrbirlbel I feel like I could spend a long time slurping through the code to figure out exactly where the duplication occurs, and I would learn a lot in the process ... but, ultimately, life's short and there's a simple solution to this question.
