# Nesting tikzpictures, style inheritance and save box

Tags: tikz-pgf

Throughout my document, I need a custom symbol, which I draw using TikZ. I have created a macro for it, so I do not need to copy the picture. I also need to use the symbol within other `tikzpicture`s. The problem here is style inheritance: the style of the outer pictures must not interfere with the symbol produced by the macro.

The answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul?lq=1) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23411/tikzpicture-in-node-of-another-tikzpicture-how-to-screen-of-from-inheriting-sty) suggest to use a savebox to overcome this problem. I have tried to do this but, so far, have failed. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

\newsavebox{\blankbox}
\savebox{\blankbox}{\hspace{0.1ex}\tikz[baseline=0.1em]{%
    \node [shape=rectangle, anchor=south, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=1ex, minimum height=0.9em] (char) {}}%
  \hspace{0.1ex}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, shorten >=1pt, >=latex]
    \node[state] (0) {$\usebox{\blankbox}$};
    \node[state, dotted, right=1ex of 0] (1) {$\usebox{\blankbox}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and its output

[image: output of the TeX code above]

As you can see, the style of the right node is inherited by the rectangle.

My question is: how can I fix this while still using the same macro everywhere?

**Edit**: In the comments Zarko suggests to change the line type in the inner picture manually. This obviously solves the problem in this specific example but what other properties do I need to set as well to "protect" the inner picture? I have tried some (like `color`, `double`, `decoration`, `rotate`) but (surprisingly to me) those aren't inherited. Does that mean that only `dash pattern` is inherited?

Comment: Using [pics](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pic) might help.

Comment: *the style of the outer pictures must not interfere* but it will.

Comment: In such a cases you need in nested images to determine type of lines. In your case `... \node [rectangle, anchor=south, draw, solid, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=1ex, minimum height=0.9em] ...`

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: I tried using a pic but the line pattern still seems to be inherited.

Comment: I'd consider it an advantage: Line style inheritance, even by saveboxed stuff! The other way around, no inheritance at all, would be much more difficult to overcome, I guess.

Comment: @AlexG: Isn't the point of using a savebox that the box is _saved_ as it is? If I don't want this behavior, I can just refrain from using a savebox. Maybe my idea of what such a box is meant to be doing is wrong.

Comment: Yes, what is in the box is saved as is. But it isn't *typeset*.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the option of switching to another engine, XeTeX will behave as you wish.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

\newsavebox{\blankbox}
\savebox{\blankbox}{\hspace{0.1ex}\tikz[baseline=0.1em]{%
    \node [shape=rectangle, anchor=south, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=1ex, minimum height=0.9em] (char) {}}%
  \hspace{0.1ex}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, shorten >=1pt, >=latex]
    \node[state] (0) {\usebox{\blankbox}};
    \node[state, dotted, right=1ex of 0] (1) {\usebox{\blankbox}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: XeTeX]

Comment: How did you even know that XeLaTeX behaves differently?

Comment: @Symbol1 `know` is a bit strong. I suspected it would. I figured if the issue is with the way the PDF itself handles things, then it would make sense that XeTeX (or TeX + whatever) might give a different result, since then we're not producing PDF directly. It seemed unlikely that inheritance would manage to survive the two-stage process. Not impossible, but unlikely. Especially since XeTeX is often problematic for just this reason: Ti*k*Z pictures don't look as they should i.e. do with pdfTeX or whatever. If it is a problem there, I figured it might be a solution here. I guessed ;).

Comment: Although I unfortunately do not have this option (arXiv does not support XeTeX), this is an amazing and astonishing answer. However, it feels more like a XeTeX/TikZ bug than like intended behavior to me.

Comment: @JPW I'm not sure it is a bug. More the nature of the beast, I think. Any more than inheritance is a bug in pdfTeX.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. You cannot protect the inner picture by a box. You cannot protect the inner picture by `.pic`. You cannot protect the inner picture even you externalize it and then include it back.

In fact, you can
[Change color in finished pdf file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65071/change-color-in-finished-pdf-file).

@Heiko Oberdiek's answer shows that it is indeed a PDF feature to inherit everything. All you can do is to reset every parameters that potentially affects the inner picture.

Fortunately, there is a finite list of parameters and can be found in PDF specification. So good luck.

Comment: So, to be safe, what I basically need to do is to compile a list of TikZ options that map to PDF parameters? This sounds a bit tedious and it is surprising to me that color is not inherited, especially in the light of the question you linked.